# Sequelize associations - please use promise-style instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to join 3 tables together `Products`, `Suppliers` and `Categories` and then get row with `SupplierID = 13`. I have read [How to implement many to many association in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25072476/2534273), there is explained how to associate `0:M`.

**DB model:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
var sequelize = new Sequelize('northwind', 'nodejs', 'nodejs', {dialect: 'mysql',})
var Project = require('sequelize-import')(__dirname + '/models', sequelize, { exclude: ['index.js'] });

Project.Suppliers.hasMany(Project.Products, {foreignKey: 'SupplierID'});
Project.Products.belongsTo(Project.Suppliers, {foreignKey: 'SupplierID'});
Project.Categories.hasMany(Project.Products, {foreignKey: 'CategoryID'});
Project.Products.belongsTo(Project.Categories, {foreignKey: 'CategoryID'});

Project.Products
    .find({
        where: {
            SupplierID: 13
        },
        include: [
            Project.Suppliers,
            Project.Category,
        ]
    })
    .success(function(qr){
        if (qr == null) throw "Err";

        console.log("---");
        console.log(qr);
    })
    .error(function(err){
        console.log("Err");
    });
```

**Log:**

```
    EventEmitter#success|ok is deprecated, please use promise-style instead.
    EventEmitter#failure|fail|error is deprecated, please use promise-style instead.
    Err
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Update: 15 Jan 15 - added `.finally()` handler. Also indicated how `.then()` is being fed with an argument from the previous handler and how to perform the next sequenced query.

The `.success`, `.error` and `.done` handlers are deprecated. The errors are not critical and it is likely that backwards compatibility will be maintained on them. But you should still change it.

As per promise A specs: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A

You now should do the following style:

```
db.Model.find(something)
  .then(function(results) {
      //do something with results
      //you can also take the results to make another query and return the promise.
      return db.anotherModel.find(results[0].anotherModelId);          
  }).then(function(results) {
      //do something else
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }).finally(function() {
        // finally gets called always regardless of 
        // whether the promises resolved with or without errors.
        // however this finally handler does not receive any arguments.
  });
```

In short:

Use `.then` instead of `.success`

Use `.catch` instead of `.error`

Use `.finally` instead of `.done`
*note: `.finally` will always get called regardless.

Comment: Actually, `finally` would be a better replacement for `done`, since it is called regardless of the success or not. But it does not have access to neither err nor the result

Comment: That looks cool, but I am using Eclipse(nodeclipse) and it displays me compilation error when using .catch (The error says: "Syntax error on token "catch", Identifier expected"). How to avoid this error?

Comment: most probably some code error like missing quotations or brackets.

Comment: Actually syntax is not problem, for example, this code causes error: doSomethingAsync().then().catch()

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with you, you can change `.success` and `.error` with single `.done(function(err, result))` to do both operation and the warning message disappear too.

Comment: [`done` is also deprecated](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0)

Comment: Also this is a classic promise anti-pattern: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern