# How to implemet a Many-to-Many relationship in Sequelizejs which also have relationship attributes?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So there are a lot of answers that explain how you model a **Many-to-Many relationship** in `sequelizejs` using `hasMany()` etc. But none of them has explained how and where do you store attributes which are created due to such an association, for eg: A customer can belong to or have many merchants and a merchant can have many customers, one such attribute of this relationship is a unique customer_id for a particular merchant-cutomer. Now where should this key(and any other detail) reside if we follow this: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958683/how-to-implement-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want additional attributes in your join table, you can define a model for the join table in sequelize, before you define the association, and then tell sequelize that it should use that model for joining, instead of creating a new one:

```
Customer = sequelize.define('customer', {})
Merchant = sequelize.define('merchant', {})
MerchantCustomers = sequelize.define('merchant_customers', {
    customer_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
})

Merchant.belongsToMany(Customer, { through: MerchantCustomers })
Customer.belongsToMany(Merchant, { through: MerchantCustomers })

customer.addMerchant(merchant, { customer_id: 42 })
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations

To access the join table attributes:

```
c.getMerchants().then(function (merchants) {
  merchants[0].merchant_customer.customer_id // Or perhaps merchant_customers, can't remember
});
```

Comment: That's good but what difference would it make if I use hasMany() instead of belongsToMany? And how can I later retrieve these attributes from MerchantCustomer, because I'll either have c.getMerchant() or m.getCustomer(). Sorry but official docs are little confusing :/

Comment: hasMany is for 1:m, while belongsToMany if for n:m. As for retrieve, see my edit