# Counting associated entries with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables, `locations` and `sensors`. Each entry in `sensors` has a foreign key pointing to `locations`. Using Sequelize, how do I get all entries from `locations` and total count of entries in `sensors` that are associated with each entry in `locations`?

Raw SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `locations`.*,
    COUNT(`sensors`.`id`) AS `sensorCount` 
FROM `locations` 
JOIN `sensors` ON `sensors`.`location`=`locations`.`id`;
GROUP BY `locations`.`id`;
```

Models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Location = sequelize.define("Location", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING(255)
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Location.hasMany(models.Sensor, {
                    foreignKey: "location"
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return Location;
};


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Sensor = sequelize.define("Sensor", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            references: {
                model: "sensor_types",
                key: "id"
            }
        },
        location: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            references: {
                model: "locations",
                key: "id"
            }
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                Sensor.belongsTo(models.Location, {
                    foreignKey: "location"
                });

                Sensor.belongsTo(models.SensorType, { 
                    foreignKey: "type"
                });
            }
        }
    });

    return Sensor;
};
```

Comment: Is that actually the `SQL` you want? I don't think that's going to do what you think it will. In fact, I'm not sure that query will run without throwing an error.

Comment: @dvlsg I run it and it correctly returned all the rows and fields in the `locations` table and for each row the right number of associated entries in `sensors`.

Comment: Actually @dvlsg, it isn't right. I did some more testing (with more entries in `locations` table) and it turned out I had forgot a `GROUP BY` statement. I've edited the question.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes more sense. I thought maybe MySQL was pulling some shenanigans I wasn't aware of (and I know they do that with implicit `GROUP` statements, so it wasn't entirely unreasonable).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496842/sequelize-hasmany-associatedmodel-count-in-attributes-in-query-execution

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use `findAll()` with `include()` and `sequelize.fn()` for the `COUNT`:

```
Location.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("sensors.id")), "sensorCount"]] 
    },
    include: [{
        model: Sensor, attributes: []
    }]
});
```

Or, you may need to add a `group` as well:

```
Location.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("sensors.id")), "sensorCount"]] 
    },
    include: [{
        model: Sensor, attributes: []
    }],
    group: ['Location.id']
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This correctly counts the `sensourCount` field but  it also includes fields from `sensors` table in the results. Also, although the SQL query it executes shows it includes all fields from the `locations` table, they aren't included in the result (the object it returns in the `then` clause).

Comment: @MikkoP okay, let me quickly build a sample and debug, thanks.

Comment: @MikkoP could you please edit the question and post your model definitions? Thanks.

Comment: I added the model definitions. Here's what your query outputs. http://pastebin.com/PwnctW1Y

Comment: @MikkoP thanks, please see the update. I think you should be able to achieve the desired result now. Thanks.

Comment: Now it produces the correct SQL query, but the returned object is still lacking the fields from `locations`. Adding `raw: true` I see all the right fields. http://pastebin.com/arv2ip3D

Comment: Changing the `attributes` value to `attributes: { include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("sensors.id")), "sensorCount"]] }` solved the problem.

Comment: @MikkoP great, fixed the answer to reflect your changes. Thanks.

Comment: It still needs the `include` part, but great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496842/sequelize-hasmany-associatedmodel-count-in-attributes-in-query-execution

Comment: @Shareef it will be fixed when you can add query option `subQuery:false` ex: `attributes:{},include:[{}],subQuery:false ` and you find more detail in https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6073#issuecomment-322068888

Answer (score 10):

**For Counting associated entries with Sequelize**

```
Location.findAll({
    attributes: { 
        include: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('sensors.location')), 'sensorCounts']] 
    }, // Sequelize.col() should contain a attribute which is referenced with parent table and whose rows needs to be counted
    include: [{
        model: Sensor, attributes: []
    }],
    group: ['sensors.location'] // groupBy is necessary else it will generate only 1 record with all rows count
})
```

**Note :**

Some how, this query generates a error like **sensors.location is not exists in field list.** This occur because of subQuery which is formed by above sequelize query.

So solution for this is to provide subQuery: false like example

```
Location.findAll({
        subQuery: false,
        attributes: { 
            include: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('sensors.location')), 'sensorCounts']] 
        },
        include: [{
            model: Sensor, attributes: []
        }],
        group: ['sensors.location']
    })
```

**Note:**
**Sometime this could also generate a error bcz of mysql configuration which by default contains only-full-group-by in sqlMode, which needs to be removed for proper working.

The error will look like this..**

Error : Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.table.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

So to resolve this error follow this answer

[SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)

Now this will successfully generate all associated counts

Hope this will help you or somebody else!

Comment: Cool, but what if you want to add a condition to the sensors table. For example, in the table there is a user_id field, how can we filter there? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes you can, pass the where attribute inside include 0th index object along with model and attributes

Answer (score 5):

```
Location.findAll({
        attributes: { 
            include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("sensors.id")), "sensorCount"]] 
        },
        include: [{
            model: Sensor, attributes: []
        }]
    });
```

and it works. but when i add "limit", i got error: sensors undefined

Comment: you can try subQuery: false in query option.

Comment: @BhavyaSanchaniya Thanks by adding   subQuery: false I am able to use limit and offset

Answer (score 3):

**Example of `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, `INNER` vs `OUTER` JOIN + several bugs/unintuitive behavior**

I went into more detail at: [Sequelize query with count in inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470383/sequelize-query-with-count-in-inner-join/69904521#69904521) but here's a quick summary list of points:

- you must use `row.get('count')`, `row.count` does not work
- you must `parseInt` on PostgreSQL
- this code fails on PostgreSQL with `column X must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` due to a sequelize bug

`OUTER JOIN` example which includes 0 counts by using `required: false`:

sqlite.js

```
const assert = require('assert');
const { DataTypes, Op, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, Object.assign({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.sqlite'
}));
;(async () => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
User.belongsToMany(Post, {through: 'UserLikesPost'});
Post.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserLikesPost'});
await sequelize.sync({force: true});
const user0 = await User.create({name: 'user0'})
const user1 = await User.create({name: 'user1'})
const user2 = await User.create({name: 'user2'})
const post0 = await Post.create({body: 'post0'})
const post1 = await Post.create({body: 'post1'})
const post2 = await Post.create({body: 'post2'})
// Set likes for each user.
await user0.addPosts([post0, post1])
await user1.addPosts([post0, post2])

let rows = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Posts.id')), 'count'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Post,
      attributes: [],
      required: false,
      through: {attributes: []},
      where: { id: { [Op.ne]: post2.id }},
    },
  ],
  group: ['User.name'],
  order: [[sequelize.col('count'), 'DESC']],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Posts.id')), Op.lte, 1)
})
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].name, 'user1')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[0].get('count'), 10), 1)
assert.strictEqual(rows[1].name, 'user2')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[1].get('count'), 10), 0)
assert.strictEqual(rows.length, 2)
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() });
```

with:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

and Node v14.17.0.

`INNER JOIN` version excluding 0 counts:

```
let rows = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'count'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Post,
      attributes: [],
      through: {attributes: []},
      where: { id: { [Op.ne]: post2.id }},
    },
  ],
  group: ['User.name'],
  order: [[sequelize.col('count'), 'DESC']],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), Op.lte, 1)
})
assert.strictEqual(rows[0].name, 'user1')
assert.strictEqual(parseInt(rows[0].get('count'), 10), 1)
assert.strictEqual(rows.length, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a database view for it and then a model for that view? You can just get the relationship to the view included in your query whenever you need the number of sensors. The code may look cleaner this way, but I'm not aware if there will be performance costs. Somebody else may answer that...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_location_sensors_count AS
select "locations".id as "locationId", count("sensors".id) as "locationSensorsCount"
from locations
left outer join sensors on sensors."locationId" = location.id
group by location.id
```

When defining the model for the view you remove the id attribute and set the locationId as the primary key.
Your model could look like this:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

const attributes = {
    locationID: {
        type: DataTypes.UUIDV4, // Or whatever data type is your location ID
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
    },
    locationSensorsCount: DataTypes.INTEGER
}

const options = {
    paranoid: false,
    modelName: 'ViewLocationSensorsCount',
    tableName: 'view_location_sensors_count',
    timestamps: false
}


/**
 * This is only a database view. It is not an actual table, so 
 * DO NOT ATTEMPT insert, update or delete statements on this model
 */
class ViewLocationSensorsCount extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
        ViewLocationSensorsCount.removeAttribute('id')
        ViewLocationSensorsCount.belongsTo(models.Location, { as:'location', foreignKey: 'locationID' })
    }


    static init(sequelize) {
        this.sequelize = sequelize
        return super.init(attributes, {...options, sequelize})
    }
}

module.exports = ViewLocationSensorsCount
```

In the end, in your Location model you set a hasOne relationship to the Sensor model.