# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1055

I'm using MySQL 5.7.13 on my windows PC with WAMP Server.

My problem is while executing this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_customer_pod_uploads`
WHERE `load_id` = '78' AND
      `status` = 'Active'
GROUP BY `proof_type`
```

I'm getting always error like this.

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'returntr_prod.tbl_customer_pod_uploads.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Can you please tell me the best solution?

My result should be like below:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | load_id | bill_id | latitude | langitude | proof_type | document_type | file_name    | is_private | status | createdon           | updatedon           |
+----+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | 78      | 1       | 21.1212  | 21.5454   |          1 |             1 | id_Card.docx |          0 | Active | 2017-01-27 11:30:11 | 2017-01-27 11:30:14 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: are saying like this     SELECT id FROM `tbl_customer_pod_uploads` WHERE `load_id` = '78' AND `status` = 'Active' GROUP BY `proof_type`

Comment: Even Still am getting the same error "Expression #1 of SELECT list is.... "

Comment: Yes, that's better. Now the question is, what if one `proof_type` maps to different `id`s? Which one should be selected?

Comment: If you want compatibility for old queries, you can turn off the `only_full_group_by` SQL mode.

Comment: If you show us sample data and desired output, I'm sure someone can give you a query.

Comment: Try using ANY_VALUE(proof_type):  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

SELECT *, ANY_VALUE(proof_type)
FROM `tbl_customer_pod_uploads`
WHERE `load_id` = '78' AND
      `status` = 'Active'
GROUP BY `proof_type`

Comment: The tricky thing here is that if you don't set sql_mode at all in my.cnf ( i.e it's absent) when you upgrade the mysql 5.7 you suddenly get this only_full_group_by issue by default . set sql_mode='' in my.cnf solves the issue

Comment: If you use Gcloud sql service, add flag sql_mode and choice traditional.

Comment: A nice answer is also over here (with how to change the mysql code): https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/237048/200937

Answer (score 619, accepted):

This

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'returntr_prod.tbl_customer_pod_uploads.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

will be simply solved by changing the sql mode in MySQL by this command.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

This too works for me.
I used this, because in my project there are many queries like this so I just changed the sql mode to *only_full_group_by*.

OR simply include all columns in the GROUP BY clause that was specified by the SELECT statement. The *sql_mode* can be left enabled.

Thank You. :-)

---

Updated:14 Jul 2023

Changing SQL mode is a solution, but still, the best practice for Structured Query Language will be avoid selecting all (SELECT * ...) columns, instead use aggregator functions on the grouping columns as mentioned by @Tim Biegeleisen below answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887524/3602846

Comment: It works for me!. You save my day.

Remember to RESTART MYSQL SERVICE

Comment: If i am using codeigniter and i want to execute in model, then how would i use it ? Can help me ? @marcode_ely

Comment: @DhavalThakor, once you run this query in your server, you no need to run again and again. so you no need to put it in your model

Comment: MySQL 5.7.29, didn't need to restart the service

Comment: I'm using the server version: 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu), and whenever I start my machine, i set it every time, Is there any permanent fix for this?

Comment: NOTE: changing the sql_mode will not affect stored procedures. So you need to drop and execute SP again to take affect

Comment: I changed global to session and it worked!
`set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

Comment: It did not work for me with global even after restart. This worked for me when I changed it in the session as Fariman. But it wasn't persistent. To make it persistent, I set the following in my.cnf
`sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` this is working fine

Comment: Including all columns in the GROUP BY clause worked.Thanks.

Comment: so, is it safe to change this? and why this option is enabled?

Comment: "OR simply include all columns in the GROUP BY clause that was specified by the SELECT statement. The sql_mode can be left enabled." I was searching for this literally for years, ^^

Comment: Scroll down and see answers(like https://stackoverflow.com/a/64890115/19261326)  to understand why this restriction exists in the first place. Don't follow this answer unless you want random results and know what you are doing.

Comment: First of all, you are not changing the sql mode to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. You just turned off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to OFF which was already ON by default and causing the error in your query. I don't think turning it OFF is a good approach. I would definitely keep it turned ON and change all instances of *group by* which triggers the exception, even if it's a big application. You may temporarily turn it off, correct all the queries with group by and the later turn ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY back to ON.

Comment: where and in which file we have to write this piece code?

Comment: @ZiaKhan that was query, so run it on a MySQL client query tool

Comment: The latest MySQL version worked. Thank you <3

Comment: If using Azure MySQL Flex Server I was able to do this through the Azure Portal Interface.  Select the Flex Server from the Resources List then select Server Parameters.  Search for SQL Mode.  Select SQL Mode and select the dropdown box.  Uncheck ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.  I did not have to restart the service although it may have in the background due to the change.

Comment: @naveed can u please check for permanent fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql

Comment: @DhanuK pls update the answer with permanent fix as well

Comment: Why is this solution not permanent?

Comment: I experienced an error during the installation of OrangeHRM. This query solved the problem

Answer (score 210):

There is a system variable **`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`** in MySql engine.

**From Mysql Version 5.7.5**: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled by default

**Before Version 5.7.5**: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` was not enabled by default.

If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default from version 5.7.5), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list refer to non-aggregated columns that are neither named in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

## To sort out the issue, use any one solution (out of below 3)

**(1) PHPMyAdmin**

**Disable**: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode

if you are using phpMyAdmin then change the **`sql_mode`** setting as mentioned in the below screenshot.
[image]

Edit `sql mode` variable and remove the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` text from the value

**OR**

**(2) SQL/Command prompt**

**Disable**: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode by running the below command.

```sql
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

**OR**

**(3) Don't use `SELECT *`**

**Do not disable** the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode but

Use relevant column in `SELECT` query. relevant means columns, which are either coming in `group by` clause or column with the aggregate function (`MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `COUNT` etc)

---

### **Important note**

Changes made by using `point(1) OR point(2)` does not set it PERMANENTLY, and it will revert after every restart.

So you should set this in your config file (e.g. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in the `[mysqld]` section), so that the changes remain in effect after MySQL restart:

**Config File**: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

**Variable name**: `sql_mode` **OR** `sql-mode`

Remove word **`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`** from the value and save the file.

**Note**: If you have not found `sql_mode` variable in the config file than please insert below 2 lines at the end of the file

```sql
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the above answer. I want to change this as you said in my my.cnf. But when I open that file, it opens only in read-only mode. Any helps or reference links???. I use Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: (1) Change the file permission of file my.cnf by using the command "chmod". 
(2) Perform changes in my.cnf
(3) set it read-only again (change file permission again using "chmod")
(4) restart mysql

Comment: I have removed that option. but still I see the error

Comment: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` This is working fine for me.

Comment: @RakeshSoni can u mention the syntax for newer versions of mysql as well as this syntax in point 3 does not allow restarting mysql server > 5.7. UPDATE: Newer versions of Mysql (e.g. 5.7.8 or above) may require slightly different syntax:

[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Answer (score 209):

When MySQL's `only_full_group_by` mode is turned on, it means that strict ANSI SQL rules will apply when using `GROUP BY`.  With regard to your query, this means that if you `GROUP BY` of the `proof_type` column, then you can only select two things:

- the `proof_type` column, or
- aggregates of any other column

By "aggregates" of other columns, I mean using an aggregate function such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, or `AVG()` with another column.  So in your case the following query would be valid:

```
SELECT proof_type,
       MAX(id) AS max_id,
       MAX(some_col),
       MIN(some_other_col)
FROM tbl_customer_pod_uploads
WHERE load_id = '78' AND
      status = 'Active'
GROUP BY proof_type
```

The vast majority of MySQL `GROUP BY` questions which I see on SO have strict mode turned off, so the query is running, but with incorrect results.  In your case, the query won't run at all, forcing you to think about what you really want to do.

Note: The ANSI SQL extends what is allowed to be selected in `GROUP BY` by also including columns which are *functionally dependent* on the column(s) being selected.  An example of functional dependency would be grouping by a primary key column in a table.  Since the primary key is guaranteed to be unique for every record, therefore the value of any other column would also be determined.  MySQL is one of the databases which allows for this (SQL Server and Oracle do not AFAIK).

Comment: Just one note: The result is not incorrect (it follows MySQL rules), but it is unpredictable, meaning, columns not part of group by and not aggregated (and not functionally dependent) will return a 'random' value from the corresponding group. As the manual states: "the server is free to choose any value from each group"

Comment: Violating strict grouping doesn't *necessarily* produce incorrect results. I usually do it when the fields are guaranteed to be identical (e.g. a one-to-many join). And even if it's not guaranteed, selecting an arbitrary row will often be no more incorrect then using an aggregate function or adding a grouping level.

Comment: +1 for me. I have no idea why the "accepted" answer above has been accepted.
Your way is the correct way and the accepted answer is the usual hacky fix which will lead to more issues in future.

Comment: @Jcov ... and I couldn't agree with your comment more +1.  Turning off the ANSI restriction on `GROUP BY` is almost always a bad idea.  It scares me that so many users are taking the wrong advice and using it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen welcome to modern copy+paste development.
"I don't need to think, someone who has read a random thing somewhere from an unreliable source has already done the thinking for me".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It answers the question of the best solution and explains why it doesn't work in the current setup. Not all developers have access to these settings or are allowed to change these settings.

Comment: +1 for "forcing you to think about what you really want to do". I wasn't doing what I really wanted to do!

Comment: It works for me! Your way is the correct way of solving this issue. You saved my day.

Answer (score 173):

**only_full_group_by = on** tells MySQL engine: Do not apply `GROUP BY` when you have doubt about what results to show and throw an error. **Only** apply it if `Group By` specifically tells you what to do. i.e. when the `Group By` is full and perfect!

**only_full_group_by = off** tells MySQL engine: always apply `GROUP BY` and if you have doubt about what results to choose, just pick one randomly!

**You don't have to turn it off if you use  `GROUP BY` properly!**

**Example:**

Table: users

```
 id   |  name
----------------
  1      ali
  2      john
  3      ali
```

When you use `GROUP BY` on the `name` column:

```
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

There are two possible results:

```
  1      ali
  2      john
```

OR

```
  2      john
  3      ali
```

MYSQL does not know what result to choose! Because there are different `id`s but both have `name=ali`.

**Solution 1:**

only selecting the `name` field:

```
SELECT name FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

result:

```
  ali
  john
```

This is a perfect solution. removing columns that makes `GROUP BY` confused. This means you know what you're doing. Usually, you do not need
those columns, but if you need them, go to **Solution 3**. (Not solution 2!)

**Solution 2:**

Turning off `only_full_group_by`. MYSQL will pick one of the two possible results **RANDOMLY**!! (It's ok if you do not really care what `id` it will choose, but remember to **turn it on** immediately after your query to prevent unexpected behaviors in future groupBys)

**Solution 3**

Use an `Aggregate` function like `MIN()`, `MAX()` to help MYSQL to decide what it must choose.

For example:

```
SELECT MAX(id), name FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

It will choose the `ali` row which has the maximum id:

```
  2      john     
  3      ali
```

**Side Note:**
Please notice MySQL does not care what data you have in your table. It's the query itself that is ambiguous. So for example you may have even no records in the table and still see the only_full_group_by error.

Comment: This answer helped me understand it best. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much to explain this issue. Now I understand better what is wrong in my query!

Comment: and if there are no ambiguous fields, because after a "LEFT JOIN" only one record goes? Then why I get this?

Comment: @JohnSmith did not quite get what you mean, but I think for your specific table data you get only one record, so if you had more (different) data, you would get multiple results? I think Mysql does not care (predict) if you will have one or many results, it's the query and the fields that comes after SELECT that are  ambiguous.

Comment: yes, it could be. Thanks.

Answer (score 46):

Below method solved my problem:

In ubuntu

Type: `sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

type A to enter insert mode

In the last line paste below two line code:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Type esc to exit input mode

```
Type :wq to save and close vim.
```

Type `sudo service mysql restart` to restart MySQL.

Comment: thanks, it worked ! in cent os, whm, my.cnf was located at sudo vi /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 32):

You can disable
**sql_mode=only_full_group_by**
by some command you can try this by terminal or MySql  IDE

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Answer (score 26):

In Ubuntu

Step 1:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Step 2: Go to last line and add the following

```
sql_mode = ""
```

Step 3: Save

Step 4: Restart mysql server.

Answer (score 24):

Hi instead of taking all columns, just take what you need by using `ANY_VALUE(column_name)`. It is working perfectly. Just check.

E.g.:

```sql
SELECT proof_type,any_value("customer_name") as customer_name
FROM `tbl_customer_pod_uploads`
WHERE `load_id` = '78' AND `status` = 'Active' GROUP BY `proof_type`
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) state "This function is useful for GROUP BY queries when the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled, for cases when MySQL rejects a query that you know is valid for reasons that MySQL cannot determine."  So if your DB user doesn't have permissions to turn off 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', this is another option to consider.

Answer (score 14):

From how it looks, I think grouping by multiple *columns/fields* wont hurt your result. Why don't you try adding to the group by like this:

```
GROUP BY `proof_type`, `id`
```

This will group by `proof_type` first then `id`. I hope this does not alter the results. In some/most cases group by multiple columns gives wrong results.

Answer (score 13):

> For the query to be legal in SQL92, the name column must be omitted from the select list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them.
>
> via [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

You can solve it by changing the sql mode with this command:

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

and ... remember to reconnect the database!!!

Answer (score 12):

**Update for MySQL 8.0**

Your `sql-mode` will not have `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` as it has been removed as mentioned here - [how-to-set-sql-mode-in-my-cnf-in-mysql-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011071/3192664)

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Also if someone doesn't have a `my.cnf` file then they can create a new one in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and then add the above lines.

Answer (score 10):

```
> sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Enter below

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ""
```

Ctrl + O => Y = Ctrl + X

```
> sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 10):

I was facing this issue and the following query **wasn't enough**

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

because I was using **Stored Procedure**. After executing this query I had to **drop the procedure and create again**.

Answer (score 10):

Two solutions:

a) Use

> SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

b) You can achieve the same effect without disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY by using ANY_VALUE() to refer to the nonaggregated column.

> ANY_VALUE(value)

Comment: I have to use it like this for it to work:

SET @@sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Answer (score 8):

go to the phpmyadmin and open the console and execute this request

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, This was my old **sql_mode**

```
sql_mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

You can check **sql_mode** with

```
show variables like "sql_mode";
```

then i SET it as this

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Answer (score 6):

Before running you query run bellow query

```
SET SQL_MODE = '';
```

Comment: But it can erase you things you need
So use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64393591/8353201 without the global

Answer (score 6):

Step 1. Check sql mode:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

Step 2. Create a new configuration file under the /etc/mysql/conf.d/ directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf
```

Enter the text below on the editor:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Step 3. Restart MySQL:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Step 4. Confirm the change:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem with part of my database crushing. What I did is I changed the parameter in the DB via PHPStorm database console like this:

```
   SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

works like charm now

Answer (score 4):

Search for "SQL mode" if you are using PhpMyAdmin and take off the value: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, just did and it okay.

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to phpMyAdmin
2. Navigate to : Server: localhost:3306 and do
   not select any database
3. Click on variables from the top menu
4. Search for "sql mode" and edit the corresponding value to : NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

That's all.

I did this in my Ec2 and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really fast and easy way of setting it permanently

NB: running `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`  is temporary and on server restart you will still end up with the error. 
To fix this permanently do the below

1. Login to your server as root
2. in your terminal run 
   `wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nfourtythree/90fb8ef5eeafdf478f522720314c60bd/raw/disable-strict-mode.sh`
3. Make the script executable by running `chmod +x disable-strict-mode.sh`
4. Run the script by running `./disable-strict-mode.sh`

And your done , changes will be made to mysql and it will be restarted

Answer (score 1):

1. Set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
2. If the problem persists and you are using Laravel, set 'strict' to false in config/database.php

   'mysql' => [
   ...
   'strict' => false,
   ...
   ],

Answer (score 1):

SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))

Answer (score 0):

### For The ones using CentOS/RHEL (Linux server) and XAMPP Locally

Hello, I've come to a very different solution and I hope this helps somone. (May look overkill but this really worked for me unlike other solutions)

I am running **CentOS 7** and all my code was working locally, but when I uploaded it to my server I started getting the error which this question addresses.

After some hours I tried viewing the problem from a different angle, I remembered that my local setup uses **XAMPP** and I thought I was using **MySQL 8** (MySQL 8 was installed on my server).

But after logging in into MySql from XAMPP I got the next output:

```
mysql -u root -p //Login


Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 27
Server version: 10.4.18-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Yes you may have noticed the same, XAMPP uses **MariaDB**, so the solution was to uninstall mysql and install MariaDB

And as I am running Centos 7 the steps to do this are the ones below:

1. Remove mysql from your server

---

```
# yum remove mysql mysql-server
```

2. Update your system (this is common everytime we install something new)

---

```
# sudo yum  -y update
```

3. Add MariaDB to repository

---

```
# sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo<<EOF 
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
EOF
```

4. Update cache

---

```
# sudo yum makecache fast
```

5. Install MariaDB

---

```
# sudo yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

6. Add MariaDB to the startup (Start MariaDB every time your system gets restarted)

---

```
#sudo systemctl enable --now mariadb
```

### Then you can secure your installation by running the next command:

```
# sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

This last command will begin a process where you can set password, and other options.

After that dont forget to add non-root user and grant it the necessary privileges, that's because you can't use root user in your applications (Yes I had to figure that out later)

### First Login using the root account:

```
# mysql -u root -p
```

### Then add your user and grant privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'YourUserName'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'YourUserName'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And finally you have to create your database, import your tables/data/triggers/procedures.

Now you will be able to run your code without any problems, just as your local setup. (Maybe you will have to install mysql extensions in case you had to do it locally too).

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply add **GROUP_CONCAT()** to the nonaggregated columns.

like `GROUP_CONCAT(your_column)`

Answer (score 0):

Login to phpMyAdmin
Navigate to : Server: http://localhost/phpmyadmin and do not select any database
Click on SQL from the top menu  and pest below code Run SQL query/queries on server
`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`
[Sorce link](https://www.findinall.com/blog/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP on Mac, any change to the variable in MySQL will be erased when you restart MAMP. To make sure the change is permanent do the following:

Stop the MAMP Servers that are running.

Use a text editor to create a file named my.cnf and save it to the /Applications/MAMP/conf folder. Put the file at the root of the folder (which seems a bit odd as it contains tons of apache folders and all but that's ok). Add the following lines into the file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Save the file and close your editor.
Start the MAMP servers.

This will make the change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode you just have to specify every columns you want to select in GROUP BY clause too.

Don't use wildcard (*) and make sure your columns are relevant for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just need to check whether your query has the right order and the way of order.

```
GROUP BY pp.id_product
FIELD(pp.id_product, 1600, 1870, 2300 );
```

This won't run until you add the direction (`DESC` or `ASC`) of the ordering to the query.

```
GROUP BY pp.id_product
FIELD(pp.id_product, 1600, 1870, 2300 ) DESC;
```

This will do the trick as well without messing with the session and global settings of the server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I can't change the global variable of mysql. (I'm using prismadB with nextJS and rawQueryUnsafe function)

But there is another way.

**select t1.field1, t1.field2, sum(t2.field3) from table1 t1 left join table2 on t1.field1=t2.field1**

*group by t1.field1 --> this fails*

**group by t1.field1, t1.field2 --> this works**

you will need to add all the required fields to the group by

Tested on NextJs 14.0.4

With PrismadB 5.11.0

Mysql server 8.1.0

Answer (score -1):

Open you  WAMP panel and open MySQL configuration file. In it search for "sql_mode" if you find it set it to "" else if you don't find it add sql_mode="" to the file.

Restart the MySQL server and you are good to go...

happy coding.

Answer (score -3):

In your `my.ini`, write this:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

depend on your version. Or:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = ""
```

or simply remove this: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: This is not a solution, it's is a terrible suggestion. It's like throwing away the smoke alarm when it starts beeping from detecting smoke in your house.