# list contains nonaggregated column 'otpallet_pokemonpalet.p.id'

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me sort out the following error:

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list
>   contains nonaggregated column 'otpallet_pokemonpalet.p.id'; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT p.id, p.question, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(a.answer SEPARATOR ';') AS answers, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(a.id SEPARATOR ';') AS answers_id 
FROM poll p 
JOIN poll_answer a ON p.id = a.poll_id 
WHERE p.status = 1 AND date_start <= NOW() AND date_end >= NOW()
```

I tried to disable only group mode but I do not have super access in cpanel ...

Comment: `WHERE p.status=1 AND NOW() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end GROUP BY p.id, p.question`

Answer (score 0):

Disabling `only_full_group_by` mode (which is ANSI SQL standard compliant) is not the right approach. You are getting this error because of usage of aggregation function `Group_concat()` alongside regular columns like `p.id` and `p.question` in the `Select`, with no mention of `Group By` details.

Due to this aggregation function, you will get a single row (without `Group By`). But MySQL has no means of identifying which `p.id` and `p.question` to return in that one row. Previous MySQL versions (< 5.7) used to be lenient about this (not ANSI standard compliant), but thankfully they have made the stricter mode as default behavior now.

You should really disambiguate your query by adding a `Group By` clause involving `p.id` and `p.question`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT p.id, p.question, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(a.answer SEPARATOR ';') AS answers, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(a.id SEPARATOR ';') AS answers_id 
FROM poll p 
JOIN poll_answer a ON p.id = a.poll_id 
WHERE p.status = 1 AND date_start <= NOW() AND date_end >= NOW()
GROUP BY p.id, p.question
```

Also, do check: [SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)