# What indexes to improve performance of JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, group-by, query-performance

I have setup some tables and ran a query. However in my explain it would appear the SQL results in a temporary table being generated ( I assume this is because of the GROUP BY)

I have added some indexes to speed up the query but wondering if there was a way to stop the use of a temporary table and if there is any other way I can speed my query up using indexes?

**CartData**

```
CREATE TABLE `cartdata` (
    `IDCartData` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CartOrderref` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `UserID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `LastUpdate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ManualContactName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `ManualOrderConfirmationEmail` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`IDCartData`),
    INDEX `CartOrderref` (`CartOrderref`)
)
```

**CartSplitData**

```
    CREATE TABLE `cartsplitdata` (
        `IDCartSupplierData` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `IDCartData` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `supplierid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `DeliveryDate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01',
        `AccountNumber` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `ManualOrderref` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `lastupdate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (`IDCartSupplierData`),
        INDEX `cartdatasupplierid` (`IDCartData`, `supplierid`)
    )
```

**My sample query**

```
        EXPLAIN SELECT max(CartData.idCartDATA) AS idCartDATA , CartData.*, CartSplitData.*
        FROM CartData
        JOIN CartSplitData ON CartSplitData.IDCartDATA = CartDATA.IDCartData
        WHERE  CartData.CartOrderref = 'XXXXXXXXX'
        group by CartSplitData.SUPPLIERID
```

**Explain of query results**
[image: Explain of query results]

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  The `group by` and `select` are incompatible.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes... I can see that now.... I have a flaw in my logic and appreciate you spotting this.

Comment: So why don't you delete this request?

Comment: The answer further down actually does achieves exactly what I wanted so glad I didn't delete the request!

Answer (score 6):

**Pro tip** Avoid `SELECT *` or `SELECT table.*` in performance-sensitive queries. Instead select, by name, the columns you actually need to use

**Pro tip** MySQL has a notorious nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY` which you are using, and possibly misusing. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html  If you followed the first pro tip, following the second would be much easier.

**Pro tip** Avoid "throwing in" lots of single column indexes in hopes of accelerating your queries. Instead, create indexes, often compound indexes, matching the needs of your actual query. Read this https://use-the-index-luke.com .

**Pro tip** `Using temporary; using filesort` appearing in EXPLAIN output is not necessarily bad. It simply means that the query engine has to cache a partial result set before returning it. The `temporary` thing isn't an actual table, it's a RAM structure. If it is so big it swamps RAM, MySQL will spill it to disk. But yours isn't.

All that being said, let's refactor your query. I guess you want to retrieve the rows with the largest `idCartDATA` value for each `CartSplitData.SUPPLIERID`.

So let's write that as a subquery.

```
                  SELECT max(IDCartDATA) AS IDCartDATA, SUPPLIERID
                    FROM CartSplitData
                   GROUP BY SUPPLIERID
```

This query can be sped up, dramatically, by putting a compound index on CartSplitData: `(SUPPLIERID, IDCartDATA)`.

Next, let's rewrite your main query to find the rows matching the ids in that subquery.

```
SELECT CartData.*             /* * hammers performance */
       CartSplitData.*        /* * hammers performance */
  FROM CartData
  JOIN CartSplitData ON CartSplitData.IDCartDATA = CartDATA.IDCartData
  JOIN (
                  SELECT max(IDCartDATA) AS IDCartDATA, SUPPLIERID
                    FROM CartSplitData
                   GROUP BY SUPPLIERID
       )x ON x.SUPPLIERID = CartSplitData.SUPPLIERID
         AND x.IDCartData = CartSplitData.IDCartData
 WHERE CartData.CartOrderref = 'XXXXXXXXX'
```

Your index on `CartData.CartOrderref` will help this outer query, as will the compound index created ^^^.

Comment: I generally avoid .* SELECTS for clarity but in this instance I didn't as I was in a rush. However now that I know it can impact performance I will alias hence forth.

Comment: Thanks very much for your full example. I will implement your suggestion.