# Finding rows which match and blanks

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a table of users and a table of electronic signatures - I want to be able to show for a given document who has signed and who has not.

Lets say we have employees:

```
EID   Name
1     Bob
2     Tom
3     Fred
```

signatures:

```
EID    Document Signature
1      1        Bob
1      2        Bob
1      3        Bob
2      1        Tom
3      2        Fred
```

My issue is that I can get this to work fine for document 4 - as no one has signed I can look where the document is null

However, if I look for document 2, for example, then I am currently getting employees missed off the list

For document 2 I would want to see

```
EID Signature
1   Bob
2 
3   Fred
```

For document 4 I would want to see:

```
EID Signature
1
2 
3
```

and for document 1:

```
EID Signature
1   Bob
2   Tom
3
```

The query I have tried to use is:

```
SELECT e.eid, s.signature 
from employees e 
left join signatures s on e.eid=s.eid 
where s.document=? or s.document IS NULL group by e.eid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- Whenever using `Left Join`, any `Where` conditions on the right-side tables, should be put in the `On` clause. Otherwise, it will filter your result-set, even if there is no matching row (losing the purpose of `Left Join`)/
- To compare `null` values, we use [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null). `= null` does not work. In this case, if we shift the conditions to `On` clause, we don't need to check for `null` values either.
- `Group By` usage is invalid and really not required. When using `Group By`, only aggregated columns or the columns specified in `Group By` should come in `Select`. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887524/2469308

Try the following:

```
SELECT e.eid, s.signature 
FROM employees e 
LEFT JOIN signatures s 
  ON e.eid=s.eid AND 
     s.document = ?
```

Comment: The is null bit was a typo - will look at the other part of the answer now, thanks for the reply