# MySQL JOIN for sorting a table with a 1 to many relationship

Tags: mysql

I may need some hand holding here, my SQL knowledge is enough to get by but not amazing, I'll break it down simple as I can.

- I have two tables: `orders` and `shippers`
- `orders` has many `shippers`, related by the `orderno` column
- `shippers` has a `move_dt` column (date/time when the order is going to be shipped)

I want to sort `orders` by the highest `move_dt` in the `shippers` table.

In other words: I want to list orders by the date/time they are shipping, and only show each order once.

This query gives me multiple instances of orders, one for each shipper it has:

```
select `orders`.*, `shippers`.`move_dt` from `orders`
join `shippers` on `shippers`.`orderno` = `orders`.`orderno`
order by `shippers`.`move_dt` desc
```

What do I need to do so each order shows only once? The query should return the same number of results as `select * from orders` but be sorted by the highest move date in the shippers table.

I'm happy to post table structures and any other relevant info, and to have edits to my post that make it more clear.

Comment: Duplicate.   See this post (if you have mysql <= 5.7) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql or this if you have mysql 8.0 : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Comment: Doblicot post at htwww:/goggle.cot/index.url?query=justUseJquerySillyGoose.html is over ther is solve for u thx for coming have good weekday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You can `Group By` on the `orderno` field; this would result in one row per `orderno`. Then, you can use [`Max()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) aggregation function to get the maximum `move_dt` value for an order. Eventually, you can sort the result based on the maximum `move_dt` value.

```
select o.orderno, -- you can add more columns here from orders table 
       MAX(s.move_dt) AS max_move_dt
from orders AS o 
join shippers AS s on s.orderno = o.orderno
group by o.orderno -- ensure to add extra column from select clause here also
order by max_move_dt desc
```

**Additional Notes:**

- Do not use `Select *`; always prefer to use names of the column(s) you want to fetch. Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)
- When using `Group By`, we need to ensure that all the columns/expressions specified in the `Select` clause are either aggregated expressions, or the columns/expressions specified in the `Group By` clause. Do read: [SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)
- It is advisable to use [Aliasing](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) when dealing with multi-table queries.

---

**Approach 2:**

We can use a [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) and fetch the maximum `move_dt` value for an order. This will do away with the `Group by`, and `Join` requirements. Now, you can specify all the column(s) from the `orders` table in the `Select` clause, without worrying about specifying them in the `Group By` clause:

```
select o.*, 
       (SELECT MAX(move_dt) 
        FROM `shippers` AS s 
        WHERE s.orderno = o.orderno) AS max_move_dt 
from `orders` AS o 
order by max_move_dt desc
```

Comment: This doesn't work if he want more than 1 column in shippers table.

Comment: @DanielBlais This is what OP states: "What do I need to do so each order shows only once?"

Comment: I want to ignore all shippers except the highest `move_dt` value per order. Just want to sort orders, don't want to show an order twice. Is it clear? Thanks guys by the way.

Comment: @WesleyMurch thanks for making it clear. My answer should be what you need.

Comment: Madhur, he want each order to show once, not each column!

Comment: @DanielBlais "The query should return the same number of results as select * from orders but be sorted by the highest move date in the shippers table." What part is not clear to you ?

Comment: @DanielBlais please if you can, give me a hand! I'm reading your links now but I'm a little lost.

Comment: @WesleyMurch please post some sample data and expected output. My answer gets one row per order, and the maximum date value for that order (from all the shippers, we pick the maximum date); and then eventually sort the results by the maximum date value

Comment: Wesley, which version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: @DanielBlais Looks like the OP is selecting ``shippers`.`move_dt`` so that they can do an `order by` , otherwise they are selecting only the columns from the orders table.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have to leave work for a bit but this seems to be what I need, much appreciated sir! I'll read up on the related links when I return.

Comment: @DanielBlais care to remove the downvote :) OP has marked accepted, as it was what he wanted originally :)

Comment: Good one @MadhurBhaiya ;)