# How to insert the values manually as well as selecting from one table, into another table at a same time?

Tags: php, mysql

Herein, I am doing this and instead of getting the MAX value for CustomerID, i am getting 0.

My CustomerData Table :

```
     Columns
```

---

```
    1   CustomerID      
    2   Name         
    3   PhoneNumber 
    4   Address
```

My OrderTable1 Table

```
 Columns
```

---

```
1   OrderID    
2   TableID 
3   OrderDate   
4   OrderStatus
5   OrderDesc   
6   CustomerID

INSERT INTO OrderTable1 (OrderDate,OrderStatus,OrderDesc,CustomerID)
VALUES ('$LenthOfService','$Quantity','$ItemName','(SELECT MAX(CustomerID) FROM CustomerData)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`INSERT INTO .. SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement. For the input variable values, we can `SELECT` them alongside maximum value of `CustomerID` from the `CustomerData` table:

```
INSERT INTO OrderTable1 (OrderDate,OrderStatus,OrderDesc,CustomerID)
SELECT MAX('$LenthOfService') AS OrderDate,
       MAX('$Quantity') AS OrderStatus,
       MAX('$ItemName') AS OrderDesc,
        MAX(CustomerID) AS CustomerID
FROM CustomerData
```

In order to be ANSI SQL compliant, we will need to use `Max()` function around the variable values. More details at: [SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)

Also, it seems that you are not using Parametrized queries. In that case, your code will be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: *"Even [`real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2469308) cannot secure it completely."* - That reference is for the mysql_* api, not for the mysqli_* api; totally different animal here.

Comment: $LenthOfService and $quantity and $ItemName, i am getting from user input through android app and these fields are not in CustomerData

Comment: @ManuKaur yeah that is why they will be used as string literals in this query. try it once

Comment: I tried now it only works for CustomerID. I have edited my question