# Can anyone solve this mysql statement WHERE COUNT problem?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Im joining two tables together, and i want to list only those rows, which groupped rows count not matching table A's pieces value.

```
table A
id     name    pieces
1      name_1    6
2      name_2    2

table B
a_id
1
1
2
2
```

So what i want is to fetch all the a.name where a.piece<>the groupped rows count.
something like this:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b
               ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE  a.pieces <> Count(*)
GROUP  BY id
```

this results an invalid use of group function
also tried this:

```
SELECT a.name,
       Count(*) AS count
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b
               ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE  a.pieces <> count
GROUP  BY id
```

> error: unknown column 'count'

In this case, as result, i only want to receive 1 row like this:

```
name     count
name_1     2
```

Because `name_1` has 2 grouped rows from `table.b` and it is not matching `a.piece` which is 6.

Comment: Instead of !== i wanted to write < > but stackoverflow wasnt showing that char combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` on `pieces`, since it is a scalar value only, it will not make a difference. This will also make the query compliant to `only_full_group_by` mode

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b
               ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP  BY a.id, a.name 
HAVING MAX(a.pieces) <> COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is only_full_group_by ?

Comment: @Ninet9 check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887524/2469308

Comment: Thanks. I'll be fine with those strict rules.

Comment: @Ninet9 yes you should use the strict mode, as it is the right way and ANSI standard compliant

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the data from tableb and join it with tablea:

```
SELECT tablea.name
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a_id, COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM tableb
    GROUP BY a_id
) AS groupedb ON tablea.id = tableb.a_id
WHERE tablea.pieces <> groupedb.c
```