# How to query Eloquent relationship, displaying only the latest records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create a relationship in Laravel that would provide me with the `latest` records only. I have three entities: `Game`, `Player` and `Turn`. I need to be able to create a relationship on `Game` to return `currentTurns` only.

This is my database:

```
Players
+--+--------+
|id|name    |
+--+--------+
|1 |John Doe|
|2 |Jane Doe|
|3 |John Roe|
+--+--------+

Turns
+--+-------+---------+----+-------------------+
|id|game_id|player_id|roll|created_at         |
+--+-------+---------+----+-------------------+
|1 |1      |1        |3   |2020-03-19 08:27:42|
|2 |1      |2        |5   |2020-03-19 08:27:46|
|3 |1      |3        |1   |2020-03-19 08:27:51|
|4 |1      |1        |6   |2020-03-19 08:28:05|
+--+-------+---------+----+-------------------+

Games
+--+--------+
|id|name    |
+--+--------+
|1 |Foobar  |
+--+--------+
```

Originally, I would write a raw SQL query somewhat like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM turns WHERE game_id = 1 GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

I found out that this [behaviour has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc) since MySQL 5.7. So I found [an approach](https://gabi.dev/2016/03/03/group-by-are-you-sure-you-know-it/) that works without having to disable the strict mode in Laravel.

My current raw query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT turns.* 
FROM turns
JOIN (
    SELECT player_id, max(created_at) as created_at FROM turns WHERE game_id = 1 GROUP BY player_id
) as latest_turns 
ON latest_turns.player_id = turns.player_id 
AND latest_turns.created_at = turns.created_at 
AND game_id = 1
```

I am not sure if this is the most performant way but I'm looking for ways to achieve this using Eloquent relationship method on `Game` class.

```php
<?php

// ...

public function currentTurns(): HasMany
{
    return $this->turns(); // ???
}
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Is it actually possible for  a player to have two simultaneous game_ids? If not, then the final condition is redundant. Alternatively, assuming ids are chronological, then this would be the better comparison. So, either way, the final `AND game_id = 1` is redundant.

Comment: Yes, the `Player` is shared across games. Integer IDs are only temporary though, which means I cannot use `max()` for them.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what your current relationships are? Is `turns` acting as a pivot table? Have you created a model for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `joinSub()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) lets you join a subquery, as you are doing in your SQL. Assuming you have a `Game::turns()` method set up, you can use it in an [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) that joins a subquery into it:

```php
class Game extends Model
{
    public function turns()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Turn::class)->with('player');
    }

    public function getLatestTurnsAttribute()
    {
        $subquery = Turn::select('player_id')
            ->selectRaw('max(created_at) as created_at')
            ->where('game_id', $this->id)
            ->groupBy('player_id');

        return $this->turns()
            ->joinSub($subquery, 'latest_turns', function ($j) {
                $j->on('latest_turns.player_id', '=', 'turns.player_id')
                    ->on('latest_turns.created_at', '=', 'turns.created_at');
            })
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Now, `Game::find(1)->latest_turns` will create the following SQL, very similar to your original (note I filtered the subquery by the game ID as well, to reduce row counts.)

```sql
select * from `turns`
inner join (
    select `player_id`, max(created_at) as created_at from `turns` where `game_id` = 1 group by `player_id`
) as `latest_turns`
on `latest_turns`.`player_id` = `turns`.`player_id`
and `latest_turns`.`created_at` = `turns`.`created_at`
where `turns`.`game_id` = 1 and `turns`.`game_id` is not null
```

[Live example is here](https://implode.io/aDirDO).

Comment: Is there a reason for the attribute vs relationship approach? I changed it to the relationship like this: https://implode.io/bT80GS.

Comment: I don’t think it makes any difference. Should be fine either way.