# show duplicate data mysql and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

i have table and records like this

[image: my table]

i want show duplicate code data with WHERE place is a ,i want foo and foo 2 to show because them duplicate but foo 2 not show

i can show all duplicate data with this query :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
         WHERE code 
              IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT code
                 FROM myTable
                 GROUP BY code
                     HAVING COUNT(code) > 1)
                  AS a)
```

but when add where

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
         WHERE code 
              IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT code
                 FROM myTable
                 GROUP BY code
                     HAVING COUNT(code) > 1)
                  AS a) AND place = 'a'
```

only show foo , i want `foo 2` to appear too because both them is duplicate

**--------UPDATE-----------**

fixed with

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m1
WHERE exists 
    (
        SELECT code
        FROM myTable m2
        where m1.code = m2.code
        and place = 'a'
)
```

but this not filter duplicate data or not, so you need to combine with `WHERE IN`

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
         WHERE code 
              IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT code
                 FROM myTable
                 GROUP BY code
                     HAVING COUNT(code) > 1)
                  AS a)
AND exists 
    (
        SELECT code
        FROM myTable m2
        where m1.code = m2.code
        and place = 'a'
)
```

but still slow to execute big data, `WHERE IN` can change with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT code
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY code
    HAVING COUNT( code ) > 1
) m2 ON m1.code=m2.code WHERE exists 
    (
        SELECT code
        FROM myTable m2
        where m1.code = m2.code
        and place = 'a'
)
```

and to make more fast just add `WHERE` after `INNER JOIN` and not use `WHERE IN` or `WHERE EXISTS`

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT code
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP BY code
    HAVING COUNT( code ) > 1
) m2 ON m1.code=m2.code 
WHERE 
    (m1.place = "a" OR m2.place = "a")
```

but this will trow error `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column … incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc/41887524) will fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following with `exists`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2nHXUWbA8uigjH9ZpFuomg/1).

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable m1
WHERE exists 
    (
        SELECT code
        FROM myTable m2
        where m1.code = m2.code
        and place = 'a'
)
```

Output:

```
| id   | code   | name  | place |
| ---- | ------ | ----- | ----- |
| 1001 | 110004 | foo   | a     |
| 1002 | 110004 | foo 2 | b     |
```

Comment: yes but i want to WHERE place = 'a' but only foo is show i want foo 2 to show too

Comment: nice ,like as I expected,but query is to heavy to handle big data i implement to my local db with 40000++ rows and i got timeout

Comment: yeah but realy slow in my case

Answer (score 0):

The  other workaround you can do with the following query

```
      SELECT tmp.*
      FROM mytable tmp
      INNER JOIN mytable tmp1 ON tmp1.Code = tmp.Code
                 And tmp1.id < tmp.Id
      WHERE tmp1.place = 'a'
```