# orderBy oneToMany relation using typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have PublicationsEntity with a OneToMany relation to LikesEntity, i'm trying to sort my publications by likes, and return all of the likes with the user associated in likes, and all the comments to display them front-side

```
@Entity('publications')
export class PublicationsEntity {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number;
    
        @Column({ type: 'longtext' })
        publication: string;

        @ManyToOne(type => UsersEntity, users => users.publications, { 
        onDelete: "CASCADE" })
        user: UsersEntity;

        @OneToMany(type => CommentsEntity, comments => 
        comments.publication, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
        comments: CommentsEntity[];
    
        @OneToMany(type => LikesEntity, likes => likes.publication, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
        likes: LikesEntity[];
    }
```

there is my likes entity who contains user and i'm trying to return each user on each like after with the sorted publications :

```
@Entity('likes')
export class LikesEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    like: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => UsersEntity, user => user.likes, { eager: true })
    user: UsersEntity;

    @ManyToOne(type => PublicationsEntity, publication => publication.likes)
    publication: PublicationsEntity;
}
```

my users entity :

```
@Entity('users')
export class UsersEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    userName: string;

    @OneToMany(type => PublicationsEntity, publications => 
    publications.user, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    publications: PublicationsEntity[];

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column({ select: false })
    password: string;

    @OneToMany(type => CommentsEntity, comment => comment.user, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    comments: CommentsEntity[];

    @OneToMany(type => LikesEntity, like => like.user, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    likes: LikesEntity[];

    @OneToMany(type => PublicationsEntity, publications => publications.user, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    publications: PublicationsEntity[];

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)" })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp", default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)", onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)" })
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

and there is my publicationsService

```
async getPublications() {
    return await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder(PublicationsEntity, 'publications')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('publications.likes', 'likes')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('publications.user', 'user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('publications.comments', 'comments')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('comments.children', 'children')
    //.orderBy()
    .getMany()
}
```

some data on my likes table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ0l5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you should fix something on ur entities
In your PublicationsEntity

```
 @OneToMany(type => LikesEntity, likes => likes.publication, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    likes: LikesEntity[]; // this one should be an array
```

and for LikesEntity

```
@ManyToOne(type => PublicationsEntity, publication => publication.likes)
publication: PublicationsEntity;
```

**For your question**, I assume that you want to return the Publication sorted by number of likes, to do that you should add in your query:

```
async getPublications() {
return await getConnection()
.createQueryBuilder(PublicationsEntity, 'publications')
.leftJoin('publications.likes', 'likes')
.addSelect("COUNT(likes.publication) AS total_likes" )
.orderBy('total_likes', 'ASC') // or DESC
.groupBy("likes.publication")
.getRawMany()
  }
```

**UPDATE**

As I understand from your comments below, I think you need to use the map and sort function to get the result you needs :

```
async getPublications() {
return await getConnection()
.createQueryBuilder(PublicationsEntity, 'publications')
.leftJoinAndSelect('publications.likes', 'likes')
.leftJoinAndSelect('publications.user', 'user')
.leftJoinAndSelect('publications.comments', 'comments')
.leftJoinAndSelect('comments.children', 'children')
//.orderBy()
.getMany().then(data => data.map(a => ({ ...a, total_likes:a.likes.length })).sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.total_likes - a.total_likes; // this's going to sort by DESC if you want to make the opposite just do a.total_likes - b.total_likes
})
)
```

}

Comment: Hello Youba,

thanks for the answer, i tried this out and i got the following error :

`Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'jesaispas.publications.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: try to change the mode [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc/41887524)

Comment: is that fix your bug?

Comment: yeah it does thanks a lot for you help ! i was wondering if you know a way to keep all of the likes during something like groupBy and using getMany(), it order my publication by likes, but i would like to display likes.length in the front side and groupBy seams to always return only one element, even if i have for example a row comments with a OneToMany relation like 'Likes' with like 20 comments it return only one item

and also for some reasons my first item using ASC / DESC is always the same publication with 0 like, i don't know why

Comment: we can't use getMany in this situation because when you are selecting other fields like the count of likes typeorm can't map it to the Entities which you have defined, because there might be aliases in the select. So you have to get that data as raw data.

Comment: what about other total_likes? is all of them 0 or you have others? do u use getRowMany right?

Comment: yeah i use getRowMany, and i got "total_likes" but the values are way more bigger than the reality, if i have like 10 real likes, total_likes return like 400 or something

Comment: it maybe count the like and the likes who has been removed ?

Comment: removed from the database?

Comment: i don't know to be honest in the key total_likes i have like 750, and my table only contains 500 likes any publications combined, so i'm gonna work on it

Comment: Can you update you question and add the structure of like table with some data

Comment: i updated my post, let me know if you need more informations

Comment: as I said earlier we can't get what you want by using getMany with typeorm, for that I suggest to use map and sort after getting the data, check my updated answer, hope that helps you