# How to combine aggregate with nonaggregated in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables Locations and competitors, i want to get the latest row from locations for each competitor order by timestamp in mysql. I don't know how to combine aggregate with non aggregate without changing the sql mode 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'

Tabels looks like

```
 Location
| lng       | lat     | competitor_id | timestamp |
| 99.99999  | 88.99999|     1666      |2021-07-29 10:40
| 65.99999  | 36.99999|     1555      |2021-07-29 10:12
| 35.99999  | 42.99999|     1888      |2021-07-29 10:28
| 28.99999  | 58.99999|     1666      |2021-07-29 10:17
| 47.99999  | 32.99999|     1555      |2021-07-29 10:42
| 22.99999  | 15.99999|     1888      |2021-07-29 10:05
 
Competitors
| Name          | team    | competitor_id
| Artial Dedino | Scuderia |     1666      
| Naruto Belica | Redb|          1555      
| Maranelino Kita | Sport|       1888
```

I try

```
SELECT c.`name`,l.lat,l.lng,l.timestamp
FROM competitors as c
INNER JOIN locations as l ON l.competitor_id = c.number
GROUP BY c.number
ORDER BY  l.timestamp DESC
```

Need result like

```
 | Naruto Belica | Redb| 2021-07-29 10:42    
 | Artial Dedino | Scuderia | 2021-07-29 10:40  
 | Maranelino Kita | Sport| 2021-07-29 10:28
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JSBach what you don't understand ?

Comment: Show your attempt (query text) to solve this task.

Comment: Your so-called result shows three columns yet your select statement is selecting many more columns. You show your timestamp column as having name `timestamp` yet in your SQL you call it `inserted_at`. Read carefully [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: @Booboo timestamp is inserted_at, i fix it thank you but this is not the reason for not working

Comment: Your column names in you select statement still do not have any resemblance to what you claim is your result. `c.number`? What is that? Do your really want as output the `lat` and `lng` columns? Don't you want `name`, `team` and `timestamp`. **We know why it is not working. The point is if we don't know what you want, we still can't give you an answer. Could anything be more clearer than that?**

Comment: @Booboo c is alias of competitors, these tables has lot of columns, i want only some of these, problem isn't select column but aggregated columns, please focus on question not on select statement!

Comment: If you knew more than you knew, you would know how off base a comment you just made. If you only wanted the `timestamp` column from the `locations` table, there would be a simple select statement for doing that. If, however, you needed multiple columns from that table, another method would be called for. That's why when there is a discrepancy between the columns you show in your select statement and the columns you claim you want in the result, there is a lack of clarity that cannot be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MySQL only_full_group_by mode is  on, it means this means that if you GROUP BY by some column, then you can only select one of two things , the column you group by and an aggregate function like  MAX(), MIN()...;
If you do not want to change your sql_mode (that may result in problems in the future ),
below query should work for you.

```
    SELECT max(name) as name,
           max(team) as team,
           max(timestamp)  as timestamp
FROM competitors join location using(competitor_id)
where competitor_id in ( 
select distinct competitor_id from  competitors ) 
group by competitor_id
order by timestamp DESC ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc8a6/1

Refrence link: [SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)

Comment: Note that this appears to be the most frequently asked question under mysql tag. Innumerable 'correct' answers have already been provided.

Comment: inserted_at is timestamp I fixed it, this query doesn't return any value @basha04

Comment: @basha04 yes sir,

Answer (score 0):

> Need result like
>
> ```
> | Naruto Belica | Redb| 2021-07-29 10:42    
> | Artial Dedino | Scuderia | 2021-07-29 10:40  
> | Maranelino Kita | Sport| 2021-07-29 10:28
> ```

```
SELECT c.name, c.team, MAX(l.`timestamp`) timestamp
FROM Competitors c
JOIN Location l USING (competitor_id)
GROUP BY c.name, c.team;
```

Comment: You can't use aggregate columns with non aggregated columns in the select list

Comment: @Sterko Last line was lost... fixed.

Comment: @basha04 OP can do this by himself if needed, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```sql
select c.name, l.lat, l.lng, l.timestamp
from competitors c
join (
    select l.* from locations where timestamp = (
        select l2.timestamp from locations where l2.competitor_id = l.competitor_id
        order by l2.timestamp desc
        limit 1
    )
) l on c.competitor_id = l.competitor_id
```