# MySQL query conversion to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB. I have done code to get the highest deaths value country-wise with their reporting date in MySQL. As the initial step, I am trying to get the max value of the deaths column, but it is returning another value that is not the highest. Here is my MySQL code:

```
SELECT 
d.country_name, s.dt, MAX(s.deaths)
FROM
Demographics d 
inner JOIN statistics s 
where d.country_id=s.country_id
GROUP BY country_name
ORDER BY MAX(s.deaths) DESC;
```

It is returning:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 2022-01-29 | 118335 |
| Bangladesh | 2022-01-30 | 34 |

What will be the equivalent code to MongoDB to get the same result?
To get the max value of the deaths column in MongoDB i used:

```
db.statistics.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country_id",
      maxQuantity: {
        $max: "$deaths"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is my sample input:

Demographics

```
{"country_id":"BGD","country_name":"Bangladesh","population":"164700000","area":"148460","density":"1265"}, {"country_id":"DEU","country_name":"Germany","population":"83200000","area":"357386","density":"232"}
```

statistics

```
{"country_id":"DEU","dt":"2022-01 29", "confirmed_cases":"2016684", "deaths":"118335"},
{"country_id":"DEU","dt":"2022-01-17", "confirmed_cases":"53916", "deaths":"143"}, 
{"country_id":"BGD","dt":"2022-01-30", "confirmed_cases":"12183", "deaths":"34"},
{"country_id":"BGD","dt":"2022-01-29", "confirmed_cases":"10378", "deaths":"21"},
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input data.

Comment: i want to retrieve the highest number of date with reporting date countrywise.

Comment: Please edit the question for additional information instead of using a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated: Post Owner request for the max `deaths` for each country.**

1. `$lookup` - Join both `statistics` and `Demographic` collections by `country_id`.
2. `$set` - Set `death` field by converting to integer.
3. `$sort` - Sort by `death` DESC.
4. `$group` - Group by `country_id`. Get first value (`$first`) as the result was sorted in Stage 3.
5. `$sort` - Sort by `maxQuantity` DESC.
6. `$project` - Decorate output document.

*Side note: It's weird to store `confirmed_cases` and `deaths` as string type.*

```
db.statistics.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Demographics",
      "localField": "country_id",
      "foreignField": "country_id",
      "as": "demographics"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      deaths: {
        $toInt: "$deaths"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      deaths: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        country_id: "$country_id"
      },
      country: {
        $first: "$demographics"
      },
      dt: {
        $first: "$dt"
      },
      maxQuantity: {
        $first: "$deaths"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      maxQuantity: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      country_name: {
        $first: "$country.country_name"
      },
      dt: "$dt",
      maxQuantity: "$maxQuantity"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dLmTgZ6wql2)

---

For MySQL query, INNER JOIN should be:

```
INNER JOIN statistics s ON d.country_id=s.country_id
```

and without the need of `WHERE`.

Comment: @Young Shun thanks. But i wanted to show only the highest value of deaths of each country like this:     
                                                                                                                                      
             Germany       2022-01-29  118335  
             Bangladesh   2022-01-30  34                                                                                                  . The above mongo code is showing all results in descending order..

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer for latest requirement. But I doubt that your MYSQL query will be fail for your new requirement.

Comment: But my sql is giving the exact results!! why is that??!!

Comment: Hi sorry about that. I guess due to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc). After I disable the FULL_GROUP_BY in [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8v4nBj92NJHPepP2uToonq/1), then it works now.