# Need guidance on MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table with values like this below one.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | ABC | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | John | AED | 52 | 15 |
| 1 | John | ABC | 12 | 10 |
| 1 | John | AED | 20 | 5 |
| 1 | John | ABC | 10 | 5 |
| 2 | Mark | DDD | 42 | 8 |
| 2 | Mark | BBB | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | Ben | EEE | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | Ben | FFF | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Ben | EEE | 2 | 3 |

I want to group them in the following manner

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | ABC | 32 | 35 |
| 1 | John | AED | 72 | 20 |
| 2 | Mark | DDD | 42 | 8 |
| 2 | Mark | BBB | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | Ben | EEE | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | Ben | FFF | 1 | 1 |

I used the

```
select col1, col2, col3, SUM(col4), SUM(col5)
from table
where [some condition]
group by col3
```

I am getting errors. Can somebody help with this?

Thanks,

Comment: Your have to create a [mre], so `SELECT ... where [some condition] ...` is not OK. when the condition is not important for your question, you could easily remove the `where [some condition]`

Comment: "I am getting errors "   Please copy/paste the complete error message (as text, not as an image)

Comment: also, the error the query is returning is the basic for debugging. You may just have a syntax error in the query you are running but not showing

Comment: You should be grouping by all non aggregating columns..

Comment: The error "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_1808046991.table1.col1' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=975783efbd4020a2aab0707d46c1e1d8)) is answered multiple times on stackoverflow.   a correct answer might be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887524/724039  (not https://stackoverflow.com/a/41887627/724039 !)

Comment: I.e. try `GROUP BY col1, col2, col3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by close must have all selected attribues

**group by col1, col2, col3, SUM(col4), SUM(col5)**

The query become :

```
select col1, col2, col3, SUM(col4), SUM(col5)
from table
where [some condition]
group by col1, col2, col3
```