# asdasdasdasdasdsad

Tags: mysql, django, docker, sql-mode

> "Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'database_name.i.id' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Hi, sorry for me English. I have a problem with MySQL and Django when I dockerize my project.
I'm new with this technologies. This is part of my docker-compose file:

```
db_mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: db_mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database_name
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
```

The problem appears when I deploy my project and enter a section. The message I showed initially appears.

I tried to apply what is mentioned in this post, but the problem persists. [SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column .... incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc)

I did the following:
I entered the container of my db:

```
docker exec -it db_mysql bash
```

I logged in to MySQL with the root user:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I placed the command to change the value of SQL_MODE:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

I checked that the change has been made:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

I exited the container and restarted it with:

```
docker restart db_mysql
```

When I go back to the project, the problem persists.

The post says that I must restart MySQL for the changes to be preserved. But when I try to run restart from the container, it tells me that the service command does not exist:

```
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: You must fix your incorrect query instead of editing the SQL Mode setting.

Comment: But I deploy the same project without docker and with MySQL in XAMPP and everything works fine.

Comment: This means that your XAMPP uses old (5.x) version of MySQL whereas in Docker container you have MySQL of version 8+. Of course you may change SQL Mode (see Bill's answer) but I think that making the queries correct is the only safe/correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have read incorrect advice. Restarting the mysqld service resets any changes you have made with `SET GLOBAL`. The configuration reverts to the defaults.

If you want to set global variables automatically when the docker container starts, you can do one of the following:

- Pass options as arguments to the command for the container
- Set options in a configuration file, and reference that file in your container

Read https://ahelpme.com/software/docker/edit-mysql-options-in-docker-or-docker-compose-mysql/ for a guide on how to do both of these methods.

That said, I agree with the comment above that you should not disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. It's important to prevent invalid queries.