# Which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

My Sql Query:

```
SELECT game_id, game_name_tr, game_name_en, game_url_tr, game_url_en, game_small_image, category_name_tr, category_name_en, category_url_tr, category_url_en, user_name, user_url, score_point FROM web_game_scores
                                                           INNER JOIN web_users ON web_game_scores.score_user_id=web_users.user_id 
                                                           INNER JOIN web_game_categories ON web_game_scores.score_game_category_id=web_game_categories.category_id
                                                           INNER JOIN web_games ON web_games.game_id=web_game_scores.score_game_id  
                                                           GROUP BY web_games.game_id ORDER BY web_game_scores.score_date DESC LIMIT 5
```

I get this error:

Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mysqldbase.web_game_categories.category_name_tr' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Please help me.

I try everyhing. Anything

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY` in your query? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc?rq=2

Comment: Remove the group by.

Comment: The error message tells you that expression 7 is the culprit....

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem myself. I added all the database fields in the SELECT partition to the GROUP BY partition and the problem went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).