# count with group and joins in sequelize node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**Below is mysql query which works**

```
select c.name, count(*) as 'count' from product p
join product_category pc on pc.product_id = p.id
join category c on c.id = pc.category_id
where p.user_id = 1
group by c.id
order by c.name;
```

**Below code doesn't seem to work.**

```
const conditionObj = { user_id: req.user.id };

const result = await db.product.findAll({
    where: conditionObj,
    attributes: [
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("*")), "count"],
    ],
    include: [
        {
            association: "categories",
            include: [
                {
                    association: "category",
                    attributes: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    group: ["categories.category_id"], // Use the correct alias for category id
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("`categories.category.name`")]] // Use the correct alias for category name
});
```

**Below is the error**

SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'heyhomie.product.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Am facing the same issues and am refer  may be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc