# Sequelize findAndCountAll and count included model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use postgresql/sequelize and findAndCountAll function.

```
   Entry.findAndCountAll({
        where: {TitleId: title.id},
        include: [
            {model: User, as: 'users', attributes: ['username']},
            {model: EntryHasLike} // I need to count this. model.
        ],
        offset: 15 * (req.body.page - 1),
        limit: 15
    }).then(entries => {
        res.json({
            title: title,
            count: entries.count,
            entries: entries.rows // [I want to count of likes inside this table]
        })
    }).catch(err => {}
```

I'm counting entries with findAndCountAll but I want additionally count of **EntryHasLikes** model which is the same with Entries.Id.

**EntryHasLike model:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const EntryHasLike = sequelize.define('EntryHasLike', {
    EntryId: {
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    UserId: {
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    likeDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW
    }
  },{
    timestamps: false
  });
  EntryHasLike.associate = function(models) {
    EntryHasLike.belongsTo(models.User)
    EntryHasLike.belongsTo(models.Entry)
  };
  return EntryHasLike;
};
```

**Entry model:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Entry = sequelize.define('Entry', {
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    entry: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    entryRev: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    entryRefId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    entryCondition: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    activity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    TitleId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {});
  Entry.associate = function(models) {
    Entry.belongsTo(models.Title, {foreignKey: 'TitleId', as: 'titles'})
    Entry.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'UserId', as: 'users'})
    Entry.belongsToMany(models.EntryCat, {through: 'EntryHasCats', as: 'entrycats'})
    Entry.belongsToMany(models.EntryTag, {through: 'EntryHasTags', as: 'entrytags'})
    Entry.hasMany(models.EntryHasLike)
  };
  return Entry;
};
```

I tried many solutions but i couldn't get result. As you see related questions in below but all of about findAll function. My function is findAndCountAll

### [Counting associated entries with Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817808/counting-associated-entries-with-sequelize)

[Sequelize 'hasMany' associated(model) count in attributes in query execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496842/sequelize-hasmany-associatedmodel-count-in-attributes-in-query-execution)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on client you can take length of `Entry.EntryHasLike`

```
setEntry(data) {
    this._entry = {
        ...data,
        count: data.EntryHasLike.length
    }
}
```