# How to get count of joined entity in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My model classes are: `Post`, `Comment` (`Post` has a one-to-many relation with `Comment`).

I want to query the count of comments on a post. So I am querying get `Post` and joining `Comment`, but I can't get joined comment's full entity length.

How do I get count of joined entity? I am thinking of the `findAndCountAll` method, but this is getting the count of `Post` instead.

Comment: Could you please share some code of what you have currently?

Comment: I would advice to include some code you tried into your post. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817808/counting-associated-entries-with-sequelize