# How to do this specific sql left join using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, database-schema

I tried to make a DB structure for voting system using sequelize like below:

```js
PollAnswer = sequelize.define('PollAnswer', {answer: DataTypes.STRING});
PollQuestion = sequelize.define('PollQuestion', {question: DataTypes.STRING});
VotingHistory = sequelize.define('VotingHistory', {});
User = sequelize.define('User', {name: DataTypes.STRING});

PollAnswer.belongsTo(PollQuestion); //every question has many answers
VotingHistory.belongsTo(PollQuestion);
VotingHistory.belongsTo(PollAnswer);
VotingHistory.belongsTo(User);
```

I want to write a query to receive the **answers of a specific question and their vote counts in VotingHistory table**, I did it using folowing sql command and response was what I expected:

```sql
select count(VotingHistory.PollAnswerId), PollAnswer.answer from PollAnswers
left join VotingHistories on PollAnswer.id = VotingHistory.PollAnswerId group by PollAnswers.id
```

expected response:

```
answer    count
------------
ans1       10
ass2       2
ans3       0
```

But when using sequelize to query the same thing like below:

```js
VotingHistory.findAll({
  where:{PollQuestionId: req.params.poll},
  attributes:[[sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('PollAnswerId')), 'count']],
  group:['PollAnswerId'],
  include:[{
    model:PollAnswer,
    attributes:['id','answer']
  }]
})
```

it just returns this:

```
answer    count
------------
ans1       10
ass2       2
```

my question is:
how can I get the expected response that **above sql command query** returns, using sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PollAnswer.findAll, sequelize.fn and include PollHistory, see [a similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817966/1376618)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I use **PollAnswer.findAll( ... include:[{ model:VotingHistory}] ...)** sequelize keep getting the error: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: VotingHistory is not associated to PollAnswer!`

Comment: you need to add an association from PollAnswer to VotingHistory like PollAnswer.hasMany(VotingHistory)

Comment: Yes thanks, by adding PollAnswer.hasMany(VotingHistory) , error problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a "typo"? The `r` is missing from `attributes`.

If not, pls see the followings:

Did you try to log what query does your script generates? You can do this, by adding `logging: console.log` to its config:

```
VotingHistory.findAll({
  logging: console.log,
  where:{PollQuestionId: req.params.poll},
  attributes:[[sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('PollAnswerId')), 'count']],
  group:['PollAnswerId'],
  include:[{
    model:PollAnswer,
    attributes:['id','answer']
  }]
})
```

However I suspect your problem is that you're using `PollAnswerId` instead of `PollAnswer.id`

```
VotingHistory.findAll({
  logging: console.log,
  where:{PollQuestionId: req.params.poll},
  attributes:[[sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('PollAnswer.id')), 'count']],
  group:['PollAnswer.id'],
  include:[{
    model:PollAnswer,
    attributes:['id','answer']
  }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your precision, that was just a typo, I edited it.