# How to count associations in sequelize in postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I have developed APIs in Node.js using sequelize framework. I use Postgres database. Please find below my table structure as below.

| category | post | category_post | user_like |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | category_id | user_id |
| category_name | title | post_id | post_id |
| detail | image_url |  |  |

I need to develop an API to filter category by provided category id and return category's posts and every post should contain total number of likes in it.

Sample JSON response is as below:

```js
{
    "data":{
        "id":1,
        "category_name":"category 1",
        "posts":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "title":"post 1",
                "total_likes":50,
                "image_url":"image.png"
            }
        ]
    },
    "success":true
}
```

Please find my code as below:

```js
sequelize.transaction().then(result => {
  return category.findOne({
    where: { "id": request.params.id }, include: [{
      model: post,
      as: "posts",
      attributes: ["id","title","image_url"],
      through: {
        attributes: []
      }
    }],
    attributes: ["id", "category_name"],
  });
}).then(posts => {
  let r = { "data": posts, "success": true }
  response.status(200).json(r)
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err)
});
```

Kindly guide me on how to get total counts of likes for post. This function doesn't work for me [Counting associated entries with Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817966/1030951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two junction tables for consideration, namely the `category_post` and `user_like` tables.  These can be handled using [many to many associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships).  For simplicity, in the code below, I treated the `user_like` table as if it were a simple child table of the parent table `posts`, leaving one remaining junction table to consider.

Also, turning on [sequelize logging](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html#logging) helps a lot with difficult queries.

Here's how I would set up the mappings.

```
let Category = sequelize.define('categories', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        category_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        detail: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
        tableName: 'categories',
        timestamps: false
    })

let Post = sequelize.define('posts', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        image_url: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
        tableName: 'posts',
        timestamps: false
    })
    
let UserLike = sequelize.define('UserLike', {
        post_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'user_likes',
        timestamps: false
    })
    
Category.belongsToMany(Post, {
    through: 'category_posts',
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: 'category_id',
    otherKey: 'post_id'
})
Post.belongsToMany(Category, {
    through: 'category_posts',
    timestamps: false,
    foreignKey: 'post_id',
    otherKey: 'category_id'
})

Post.hasMany(UserLike, {
    foreignKey: 'post_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
})
UserLike.belongsTo(Post, {
    foreignKey: 'post_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
})
```

And then I'd use a subquery like this.  Note that the parentheses around the literal select statement are necessary in order to make it a [sequelize subquery](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html).

```
let results = await Category.findAll({
        attributes: {
            exclude: [ 'detail' ]
        },
        where: { id: request.params.id },
        include: {
            model: Post,
            attributes: {
                include: [
                    [ sequelize.cast(sequelize.literal('(select count(*) from user_likes as ul where ul.post_id = posts.id)'), 'integer'), 'likes' ]
                ]
            }
        }
    })
```

This produces the following results:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "category 1",
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Post 1",
        "image_url": "http://example.com/image1.png",
        "likes": 3,
        "category_posts": {
          "category_id": 1,
          "post_id": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Post 2",
        "image_url": "http://example.com/image2.png",
        "likes": 2,
        "category_posts": {
          "category_id": 1,
          "post_id": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Alternatively, as suggested by `HarshIT`, you could use aggregation and a group by clause with the following query:

```
let results = await Category.findAll({
        attributes: {
            exclude: [ 'detail' ],
            include: [[sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('posts->UserLikes.post_id')), 'integer'), 'total_likes']]
        },
        where: { id: request.params.id },
        include: {
            model: Post,
            include: {
                model: UserLike
            }
        },
        group: [
            'categories.id',
            'posts.id',
            'posts->category_posts.category_id',
            'posts->category_posts.post_id',
            'posts->UserLikes.post_id',
            'posts->UserLikes.user_id'
        ]
    })
```

Which would produce results of the form:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "category 1",
    "total_likes": 1,
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Post 1",
        "image_url": "http://example.com/image1.png",
        "category_posts": {
          "category_id": 1,
          "post_id": 1
        },
        "UserLikes": [
          {
            "post_id": 1,
            "user_id": 5
          },
          {
            "post_id": 1,
            "user_id": 6
          },
          {
            "post_id": 1,
            "user_id": 9
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Post 2",
        "image_url": "http://example.com/image2.png",
        "category_posts": {
          "category_id": 1,
          "post_id": 2
        },
        "UserLikes": [
          {
            "post_id": 2,
            "user_id": 5
          },
          {
            "post_id": 2,
            "user_id": 8
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andrew, I have same associations as you mentioned above. When I try the query as you mentioned above, it gives error "relation "user_likes" does not exist".

Comment: I tried using "[sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("posts->user_likes.id")), 'integer'), "total_likes"]" and it worked, although I required to add group : ["category.id","posts.id"].

Comment: Is it possible to get boolean if user has already liked the video ?

Comment: @HarshIT that's great!  I had to use sequelize logging to see the query that sequelize was sending to the database.  As for returning a boolean if the user has already liked the video, you might try adding another literal element for a second subquery to the `include` array using a [sql case statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).  Also, if the query gets too complex, it's always worth considering writing a [raw sql query](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements) instead.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @HarshIT It might be possible to modify the query in the above answer by replacing "user_likes" with "posts->user_likes" to fix the error that you were getting.  Sequelize is probably coming up with some strange aliases for the table names when it auto-generates the query to hand off to the database, which might have been causing the error you were getting about 'relation "user_likes" does not exist.'

Comment: Thanks. I created custom function to count likes. querying seems easier than ORM way.

Comment: can you please edit your answer with my snippet ? I would like to accept your answer as solution. Thanks

Comment: @HarshIT I've added an alternative solution using a `group` option, as you suggested.