# Return flat object from sequelize with association

Tags: json, sequelize.js, flatten

I am working on converting all my queries in sequelize. 
The problem I have come across is that when select queries include associations (ex. one to many), the object I get is an array of nested objects.

It looks something like:

```
[   
  {
    "field1": "someval",
    "field2": "someval1",
    "assoc_table": {
      "field_a": 1,
      "field_b": "someval"
    }   
  },   
  {
    "field1": "someval",
    "field2": "someval3",
    "assoc_table": {
      "field_a": 5,
      "field_b": "someval"
    }   
  },   
  {
    "field1": "someval",
    "field2": "someval3",
    "assoc_table": {
      "field_a": 12,
      "field_b": "someval"
    }   
   } 
]
```

I tried to use different modules to flatten the objects (inside a loop, each object individually), but I always got an error telling that what I was trying to flatten were not just objects.

Moreover, I would prefer avoiding the part where objects are flattened, and simply get a flat result with sequelize.

The sequelize code looks something like this:

```
models.table1.findAll({
    attributes: ['field1', 'field2'],
    where: {field1: someval},
    include: [{model: models.assoc_table, required: true, attributes:['field_a', 'field_b']}]
}).then(function (result) {
    res.send(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Related issues: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4419 | https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11579

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of your issue is probably that your `result` is an array of model instances, so you might be having issues flattening it if you didn't call `toJSON` on the elements in the array. I provided code that would flatten your example:

```
result.forEach(obj => { 
    Object.keys(obj.toJSON()).forEach(k => {
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {       
            Object.keys(obj[k]).forEach(j => obj[j] = obj[k][j]);
        }
    });
});
```

You can also add `raw: true` as an option to `findAll`, which will flatten your object, but it will look like this:

```
[   
  {
    "field1": "someval",
    "field2": "someval1",
    "assoc_table.field_a": 1,
    "assoc_table.field_b": "someval"
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but as I was attempting to do this also and found a pure sequelize solution that does not require the "after" mapping, I wanted to add that here. So to have sequelize itself return the desired object format, it would be this, where the `attributes` are explicitly assigned based off column return values from the `include` table:

```
models.table1.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'field1', 
      'field2',
      [sequelize.col('models.assoc_table.field_a'), 'field_a'], // Set key
      [sequelize.col('models.assoc_table.field_b'), 'field_b'], // Set key
    ],
    where: {field1: someval},
    include: [
     {model: models.assoc_table, 
      required: true, 
      attributes:[], // Explicitly do not send back nested key's
     }
   ]
})
```

Comment: your solution doesn't work for me. I get run time error "attr.includes is not a function".

Can you pls look into this question of mine and provide any help if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064626/select-columns-from-right-side-table-in-inner-join-using-sequelize

Answer (score 2):

old question, but with new sequelize updates, use both:

```
raw:true,
nest:true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `raw: true` a helper function can simplify the return keys.  This will make sure no values are over-written and gives a way to keep some of string-based nesting (IDs for example).

```js
/**
  Simplify keys returned by a sequelize {raw: true} query. Makes sure no values
  are over-written and gives a way to keep some of string-based nesting (IDs for
  example).

  @example result.map(r => trimKeys(r))
*/
function trimKeys(obj, deepin = ['id']) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  const ret = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const key = keys[i]
    const keyParts = key.split('.')
    let idx = 1
    let newKey = keyParts[keyParts.length - idx]
    while((ret[newKey] || deepin.find(d => newKey === d)) && idx >= 0) {
      idx++
      newKey = keyParts[keyParts.length - idx] + '.' + newKey
    }
    ret[newKey] = obj[key]
  }
  return ret
}
```