# Sequelize: multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

Article - User - Tag - Followers - Suscribes

Article belongs to User (fk: userId in Article table)

Article can have many tag. Here is the generated tagarticle table:

[image]

Here is followers table:

[image]

And the Suscribes table:

[image]

A user can follow many users and suscribe to a country(payId), a tag or an article(for notifications).

How to query all articles of followed users and suscribed country or tag for a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you ask about Sequelize way of doing the query.
I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You are looking for two queries:

- Query all articles of followed users,
- Query subscribed country/tag/article of specific user,

Let me start with the associations made between the models.

```
// in User model definition
User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Followers', through: 'Followers', foreignKey: 'userId', otherKey: 'followId' });
User.hasMany(Subscribe, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
User.hasMany(Article, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

With use of above association we are now able to query all articles of followed users

```
models.User.findByPrimary(1, {
    include: [
        {
            model: models.User,
            as: 'Followers',
            include: [ models.Article ]
        }
    ]
}).then(function(user){
    // here you have user with his followers and their articles
});
```

Above query would generate result similar to

```
{
    id: 1,
    Followers: [
        {
            id: 4,
            Articles: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'article title' // some example field of Article model
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to query country/tag/article subscribed by specific user, you would have to make another associations in `Subscribe` model

```
// in Subscribe model definition
Subscribe.belongsTo(Tag, { foreignKey: 'tagId' });
Subscribe.belongsTo(Article, { foreignKey: 'articleId' });
Subscribe.belongsTo(Country, { foreignKey: 'payId' });
```

Now we have all the associations required to perform the second query you asked for

```
models.User.findByPrimary(1, {
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Subscribe,
            include: [ models.Tag, models.Country, models.Article ]
        }
    ]
}).then(function(user){
    // here you get user with his subscriptions
});
```

In this example you get user with all his subscriptions accessed via `user.Subscribes`, which will have nested attributes `Tag`, `Country` and `Article`. If user subscribed to `Tag`, both `Country` and `Article` would be `NULL` in this case.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal runnable example of getting articles by followed users with assertions**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634024/895245 was correct, here is a runnable version of it, also covering some other related functionality like limit and ordering. Further examples of interest at: [How to implement many to many association in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958683/how-to-implement-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize/67973948#67973948) tested on:

```
npm install sequelize@6.5.1 sqlite3@5.0.2
```

Source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'db.sqlite3',
});

(async () => {

// Create the tables.
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
}, {});
User.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserFollowUser', as: 'Follows'});
User.hasMany(Post);
Post.belongsTo(User);
await sequelize.sync({force: true});

// Create data.
const users = await User.bulkCreate([
  {name: 'user0'},
  {name: 'user1'},
  {name: 'user2'},
  {name: 'user3'},
])

const posts = await Post.bulkCreate([
  {body: 'body00', UserId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body11', UserId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body10', UserId: users[1].id},
  {body: 'body11', UserId: users[1].id},
  {body: 'body20', UserId: users[2].id},
  {body: 'body21', UserId: users[2].id},
  {body: 'body30', UserId: users[3].id},
  {body: 'body31', UserId: users[3].id},
])

await users[0].addFollows([users[1], users[2]])

// Get all posts by authors that user0 follows.
// The posts are placed inside their respetive authors under .Posts
// so we loop to gather all of them.
{
  const user0Follows = (await User.findByPk(users[0].id, {
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'Follows',
        include: [
          {
            model: Post,
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  })).Follows
  const postsFound = []
  for (const followedUser of user0Follows) {
    postsFound.push(...followedUser.Posts)
  }
  postsFound.sort((x, y) => { return x.body < y.body ? -1 : x.body > y.body ? 1 : 0 })
  assert(postsFound[0].body === 'body10')
  assert(postsFound[1].body === 'body11')
  assert(postsFound[2].body === 'body20')
  assert(postsFound[3].body === 'body21')
  assert(postsFound.length === 4)
}

// With ordering, offset and limit.
// The posts are placed inside their respetive authors under .Posts
// The only difference is that posts that we didn't select got removed.

{
  const user0Follows = (await User.findByPk(users[0].id, {
    offset: 1,
    limit: 2,
    // TODO why is this needed? It does try to make a subquery otherwise, and then it doesn't work.
    // https://selleo.com/til/posts/ddesmudzmi-offset-pagination-with-subquery-in-sequelize-
    subQuery: false,
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'Follows',
        include: [
          {
            model: Post,
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  })).Follows
  assert(user0Follows[0].name === 'user1')
  assert(user0Follows[1].name === 'user2')
  assert(user0Follows.length === 2)
  const postsFound = []
  for (const followedUser of user0Follows) {
    postsFound.push(...followedUser.Posts)
  }
  postsFound.sort((x, y) => { return x.body < y.body ? -1 : x.body > y.body ? 1 : 0 })
  // Note that what happens is that some of the
  assert(postsFound[0].body === 'body11')
  assert(postsFound[1].body === 'body20')
  assert(postsFound.length === 2)

  // Same as above, but now with DESC ordering.
  {
    const user0Follows = (await User.findByPk(users[0].id, {
      order: [[
        {model: User, as: 'Follows'},
        Post,
        'body',
        'DESC'
      ]],
      offset: 1,
      limit: 2,
      subQuery: false,
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'Follows',
          include: [
            {
              model: Post,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    })).Follows
    // Note how user ordering is also reversed from an ASC.
    // it likely takes the use that has the first post.
    assert(user0Follows[0].name === 'user2')
    assert(user0Follows[1].name === 'user1')
    assert(user0Follows.length === 2)
    const postsFound = []
    for (const followedUser of user0Follows) {
      postsFound.push(...followedUser.Posts)
    }
    // In this very specific data case, this would not be needed.
    // because user2 has the second post body and user1 has the first
    // alphabetically.
    postsFound.sort((x, y) => { return x.body < y.body ? 1 : x.body > y.body ? -1 : 0 })
    // Note that what happens is that some of the
    assert(postsFound[0].body === 'body20')
    assert(postsFound[1].body === 'body11')
    assert(postsFound.length === 2)
  }

  // Here user2 would have no post hits due to the limit,
  // so it is entirely pruned from the user list as desired.
  // Otherwise we would fetch a lot of unwanted user data
  // in a large database.
  const user0FollowsLimit2 = (await User.findByPk(users[0].id, {
    limit: 2,
    subQuery: false,
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'Follows',
        include: [ { model: Post } ],
      },
    ],
  })).Follows
  assert(user0FollowsLimit2[0].name === 'user1')
  assert(user0FollowsLimit2.length === 1)

  // Case in which our post-sorting is needed.
  // TODO: possible to get sequelize to do this for us by returning
  // a flat array directly?
  // It's not big deal since the LIMITed result should be small,
  // but feels wasteful.
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502699/return-flat-object-from-sequelize-with-association
  // https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4419
  {
    await Post.truncate({restartIdentity: true})
    const posts = await Post.bulkCreate([
      {body: 'body0', UserId: users[0].id},
      {body: 'body1', UserId: users[1].id},
      {body: 'body2', UserId: users[2].id},
      {body: 'body3', UserId: users[3].id},
      {body: 'body4', UserId: users[0].id},
      {body: 'body5', UserId: users[1].id},
      {body: 'body6', UserId: users[2].id},
      {body: 'body7', UserId: users[3].id},
    ])
    const user0Follows = (await User.findByPk(users[0].id, {
      order: [[
        {model: User, as: 'Follows'},
        Post,
        'body',
        'DESC'
      ]],
      subQuery: false,
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'Follows',
          include: [
            {
              model: Post,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
    })).Follows
    assert(user0Follows[0].name === 'user2')
    assert(user0Follows[1].name === 'user1')
    assert(user0Follows.length === 2)
    const postsFound = []
    for (const followedUser of user0Follows) {
      postsFound.push(...followedUser.Posts)
    }
    // We need this here, otherwise we would get all user2 posts first:
    // body6, body2, body5, body1
    postsFound.sort((x, y) => { return x.body < y.body ? 1 : x.body > y.body ? -1 : 0 })
    assert(postsFound[0].body === 'body6')
    assert(postsFound[1].body === 'body5')
    assert(postsFound[2].body === 'body2')
    assert(postsFound[3].body === 'body1')
    assert(postsFound.length === 4)
  }
}

await sequelize.close();
})();
```

**Super many to many to do the "posts by followed users" query without post processing**

[Super many to many](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html) means explicitly setting `belongsTo`/`hasMany` between each model and the through table, in addition to the `belongsToMany` of each model.

This is the only way I found to nicely make the "posts by followed users" query without post processing.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Op } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.' + path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },
});

(async () => {

// Create the tables.
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
const UserFollowUser = sequelize.define('UserFollowUser', {
    UserId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    FollowId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
  }
);

// Super many to many.
User.belongsToMany(User, {through: UserFollowUser, as: 'Follows'});
UserFollowUser.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(UserFollowUser)

User.hasMany(Post);
Post.belongsTo(User);

await sequelize.sync({force: true});

// Create data.
const users = await User.bulkCreate([
  {name: 'user0'},
  {name: 'user1'},
  {name: 'user2'},
  {name: 'user3'},
])
const posts = await Post.bulkCreate([
  {body: 'body0', UserId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body1', UserId: users[1].id},
  {body: 'body2', UserId: users[2].id},
  {body: 'body3', UserId: users[3].id},
  {body: 'body4', UserId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body5', UserId: users[1].id},
  {body: 'body6', UserId: users[2].id},
  {body: 'body7', UserId: users[3].id},
])
await users[0].addFollows([users[1], users[2]])

// Get all the posts by authors that user0 follows.
// without any post process sorting. We only managed to to this
// with a super many to many, because that allows us to specify
// a reversed order in the through table with `on`, since we need to
// match with `FollowId` and not `UserId`.
{
  const postsFound = await Post.findAll({
    order: [[
      'body',
      'DESC'
    ]],
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        attributes: [],
        required: true,
        include: [
          {
            model: UserFollowUser,
            on: {
              FollowId: {[Op.col]: 'User.id' },
            },
            attributes: [],
            where: {UserId: users[0].id},
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  })
  assert.strictEqual(postsFound[0].body, 'body6')
  assert.strictEqual(postsFound[1].body, 'body5')
  assert.strictEqual(postsFound[2].body, 'body2')
  assert.strictEqual(postsFound[3].body, 'body1')
  assert.strictEqual(postsFound.length, 4)
}

await sequelize.close();
})();
```