# exclude through attributes in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join, sequelize.js

I have 2 tables post and tags. I'm using Tag to get all the posts associated with it.

```
models.Tag.findAll({
attributes: ['tagName'],
include: [
 {model: models.Post
  attributes: ['content']
  through: {
   attributes: []
  }
 }
]
})
```

The problem is that it selects all the through table attributes in the query.

Although doing `include.through.attributes = []` the attributes don't show up in the result query but when I `console.log` the `select` query, it's still selecting all the attributes of the through table.

Is there to exclude the through table? it makes groupBy impossible in Postgres, cuz its selecting all the columns automatically.

Comment: There is a ticket on github concerning this problem, which, as I can see, you have already commented, so I think that the solution for this issue will appear there first ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't reproduce on `sequelize@6.5.1 sqlite3@5.0.2` with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Find all posts by users that a given user follows.
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632943/sequelize-multiple-where-clause

const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');

const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp.' + path.basename(__filename) + '.sqlite',
});

(async () => {

// Create the tables.
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
  body: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
User.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserFollowUser', as: 'Follows'});
User.hasMany(Post);
Post.belongsTo(User);
await sequelize.sync({force: true});

// Create data.
const users = await User.bulkCreate([
  {name: 'user0'},
  {name: 'user1'},
  {name: 'user2'},
  {name: 'user3'},
])

const posts = await Post.bulkCreate([
  {body: 'body00', UserId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body01', UserId: users[0].id},
  {body: 'body10', UserId: users[1].id},
  {body: 'body11', UserId: users[1].id},
  {body: 'body20', UserId: users[2].id},
  {body: 'body21', UserId: users[2].id},
  {body: 'body30', UserId: users[3].id},
  {body: 'body31', UserId: users[3].id},
])

await users[0].addFollows([users[1], users[2]])

const user0Follows = await User.findByPk(users[0].id, {
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('Follows.Posts.id')), 'count']
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'Follows',
      attributes: [],
      //through: { attributes: [] },
      include: [
        {
          model: Post,
          attributes: [],
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
})
assert.strictEqual(user0Follows.dataValues.count, 4);

await sequelize.close();
})();
```

The prettified generated SELECT is:

```
SELECT
  `User`.`id`,
  COUNT(`Follows->Posts`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM
  `Users` AS `User`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `UserFollowUser` AS `Follows->UserFollowUser` ON `User`.`id` = `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`UserId`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `Users` AS `Follows` ON `Follows`.`id` = `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`FollowId`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `Posts` AS `Follows->Posts` ON `Follows`.`id` = `Follows->Posts`.`UserId`
WHERE
  `User`.`id` = 1;
```

If I remove the `through: { attributes: [] },` then the through attributes appear, so the statement is doing something as expected:

```
SELECT
  `User`.`id`,
  COUNT(`Follows->Posts`.`id`) AS `count`,
  `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`createdAt` AS `Follows.UserFollowUser.createdAt`,
  `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`updatedAt` AS `Follows.UserFollowUser.updatedAt`,
  `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`UserId` AS `Follows.UserFollowUser.UserId`,
  `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`FollowId` AS `Follows.UserFollowUser.FollowId`
FROM
  `Users` AS `User`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `UserFollowUser` AS `Follows->UserFollowUser` ON `User`.`id` = `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`UserId`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `Users` AS `Follows` ON `Follows`.`id` = `Follows->UserFollowUser`.`FollowId`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `Posts` AS `Follows->Posts` ON `Follows`.`id` = `Follows->Posts`.`UserId`
WHERE
  `User`.`id` = 1;
```

so likely this was fixed.