# Sequelize nodejs return flat JSON

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with nodejs for a RESTful API. I have 2 models, Security and Orders. The order model references the security model using a foreign key via symbol.

**Security model:**

```
classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations
        security.hasMany(models.order, { foreignKey: 'security_symbol' });
      }
    }
```

**Order model:**

```
classMethods: {
      // associations
      associate: function(models) {
        order.belongsTo(models.security, { foreignKey: 'security_symbol' })
      }
    }
```

I then perform a query to return all orders which is working OK, though I want some other attributes of the security model to be included in a sort of 'flattened' json.
**Query:**

```
Order.findAndCountAll({
        where: { user_id: user.id},
        attributes: [
            'id', 'side', 'quantity', 'price', 'status', 'created_at'
        ],
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC']
        ],
        include: [{ model: models.security, attributes: ['name', 'symbol'] }]

    })
```

**Response:**

```
"orders": [
    {
      "id": 25,
      "side": 1,
      "quantity": 1150,
      "price": "13.33",
      "status": 0,
      "created_at": "2017-04-27T09:51:41.479Z",
      "security": {
        "name": "Car & General (K) Ltd",
        "symbol": "C&G"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "side": 1,
      "quantity": 1000,
      "price": "5.63",
      "status": 4,
      "created_at": "2017-04-27T09:50:31.939Z",
      "security": {
        "name": "Eveready East Africa Ltd",
        "symbol": "EVRD"
      }
    }...
```

**Desired Response:**

```
"orders": [
    {
      "id": 25,
      "side": 1,
      "quantity": 1150,
      "price": "13.33",
      "status": 0,
      "created_at": "2017-04-27T09:51:41.479Z",
      "security_name": "Car & General (K) Ltd",
      "security_symbol": "C&G"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "side": 1,
      "quantity": 1000,
      "price": "5.63",
      "status": 4,
      "security_name": "Eveready East Africa Ltd",
      "security_symbol": "EVRD"
      "created_at": "2017-04-27T09:50:31.939Z",

    }...
```

Difference being the 'parent' not being nested inside the order.

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502699/return-flat-object-from-sequelize-with-association

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `raw` attribute like below

```
Order.findAndCountAll({
        where: { user_id: user.id},
        attributes: [
            'id', 'side', 'quantity', 'price', 'status', 'created_at'
        ],
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC']
        ],
        include: [{ model: models.security, attributes: ['name', 'symbol'] }]
        raw: true
    })
```

But then sequelize will give you result like

```
"orders": [
    {
      "id": 25,
      "side": 1,
      "quantity": 1150,
      "price": "13.33",
      "status": 0,
      "created_at": "2017-04-27T09:51:41.479Z",
      "security.name": "Car & General (K) Ltd",
      "security.symbol": "C&G"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "side": 1,
      "quantity": 1000,
      "price": "5.63",
      "status": 4,
      "security.name": "Eveready East Africa Ltd",
      "security.symbol": "EVRD"   
    }...
```

I'm not sure if `security.name`& `security.symbol` is desirable or not. But this is how sequelize will behave. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Order.findAndCountAll({
        where: { user_id: user.id},
        attributes: [
            'id', 'side', 'quantity', 'price', 'status', 'created_at',
            [Sequelize.literal('"order->security".name'), 'security_name'],
            [Sequelize.literal('"order->security".symbol'), 'security_symbol']
        ],
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC']
        ],
        include: [{ model: models.security, attributes: []}]

    })
```

Please note you might need to update `order->security` to actual DB table names (`orders` and `securities`)

Comment: You could also use `sequelize.col()` as found in this SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922156/3736404

Comment: agree, but `Sequelize.col()` (it's a static method) is less agnostic for name changes as you lose the ability to reference the model by the name as sequelize knows it (and that's what `literal` is designed for - to use the engine to put in the right field name)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include any additional flags and you want to flattened object in for only one caller and not in all the places you can do something like this

```
async function getOrders(){
Order.findAndCountAll({
        where: { user_id: user.id},
        attributes: [
            'id', 'side', 'quantity', 'price', 'status', 'created_at'
        ],
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC']
        ],
        include: [{ model: models.security, attributes: ['name', 'symbol'] }]

    })}
const orders = await getOrders();
return orders.map(order=>order.get({raw:true}))
```