# How to get join data result without prefix table name in Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize ORM in node js. I am join two table and get result but that result return with table name as prefix.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('test', 'root', '', {
    // configuration
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;  
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.role = require('./../model/definitions/role')(sequelize, Sequelize);  
db.admin = require('./../model/definitions/admin')(sequelize, Sequelize);  

  db.admin.findAll({ 
    include: [{ 
      model: db.role,                      
      where:{status : 'Active'},     
    }],
    raw: true      

  }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }).done();
```

Now I am getting this result:

```
[{
    "id": 36,                
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "username": "test",
    "status": "Active",
    "role.role_id": 1,
    "role.role_name": "Admin"
}]
```

but I need this result:

```
[{
    "id": 36,                
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "username": "test",
    "status": "Active",
    "role_id": 1,
    "role_name": "Admin"
}]
```

so, how to remove prefix  table name 'role' from column.
I have only need 'role_id' or 'role_name' not need this type data like 'role.role_id', 'role.role_name'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should work,

```
db.admin.findAll({ 
    attributes: ['id', 'username', 'email', 'status', 'role.role_id', 'role.role_name'],
    include: [{ 
      model: db.role,                      
      where:{status : 'Active'}, 
      attributes: []
    }],
    raw: true
})
```

I found this [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7605#issuecomment-303743560)

Comment: And if you want to rename the column additionally, use `[Sequelize.col('role.role_id'), 'rid']` instead of `role.role_id`.

Comment: cause error when use `underscored` config

Comment: It doesn't work in multi-level joins. Lets say, Table A includes ( Table B includes Table C ). I cannot select Table C columns in Table B ( it always prefixes table A )

Comment: this one doesn't work with me,  but this works [`Sequelize.col(role.role_id), 'role_id']`]

Answer (score 5):

This should work

`A` is a table that is associated to `B` using a column called `bId` so B has a primary key of `Id` which is associates to a `bid` column in `A` table  that is shown in the standard result set as `b.id` but we want these two column to be called as `Id & Name`

```
A.belongsTo(B);
        return await A.findAll({
            attributes: [
                [Sequelize.col('b.id'), 'Id'],
                [Sequelize.col('b.name'), 'Name']
            ],
            raw: true,
            where: { /*Some condition*/ },
            include: {
                model: B,
                attributes: [],
                required: true
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The top level model also can be modified to exclude and include the properties if the query still want to use along with

```
raw: true

 db.admin.findAll({ 
    include: [{ 
      model: db.role,                      
      where:{status : 'Active'},
      attributes: ["role_id", "role_name"],  
      nested: false,  
    }],
    attributes: {exclude: [],
                 include: ["role.role_id", "role.role_name"]},
    raw: true      
  });
```

additionally you can have aliases as well

```
 db.admin.findAll({ 
    include: [{ 
      model: db.role,                      
      where:{status : 'Active'},
      attributes: [["role_id", "roleId"], ["role_name", "roleName"]] 
    }],
    attributes: {exclude: [],
                 include: ["role.roleId", "role.roleName"]},
    raw: true      
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work with aliases. I tried adding alias both in the atributes of parent and child models. Each time I get "Unknown column 'tableName.aliasName' in 'field list'". It works without alias though.

Answer (score 0):

`raw: true ,` causes the issue while returning data with associations , solution to this is :

**Remove :**

```
raw: true
```

**From :**

```
db.admin.findAll({ 
    include: [{ 
      model: db.role,                      
      where:{status : 'Active'},     
    }],
    raw: true // <--------- Remove this   
})
```

Comment: i need result at same level. if remove 'raw: true' then join table data show as object in 'role' key.

Comment: @MukeshSinghThakur , you can access that `role['role_id'] `, you can't get those property to upper level , as it may override the parent keys. This is the standard way to get data.

Comment: You are right  but i need this result at same level.

Comment: @MukeshSinghThakur, Then you have to use alias name in attributes , for single attribute . `['$role. role_id$','role_id']` , something like this , but for each attribute

Comment: I have also try ['$role. role_id$','role_id'] but can't get that result.