# Sequelize ORM return a weird response after inner join tables in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use sequelize orm to manage my data base (mysql).

I make a inner join that work good but the problem that the table that join return a weird variable.

this is my code

```
const getReports = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    models.Report.findAll({
      where: { companyID: [513603324, 515490704, 511493827] },
      include: [{
        model: models.Reports_type,
        attributes:["name"],
        required: true
      }],
      raw: true
    })
      .then(result => {
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

The output is

```
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "creatorUserID": 1,
        "currentUserEditorID": 1,
        "companyID": 511493827,
        "stageID": 1,
        "scenarioID": 1,
        "typeID": 1,
        "year": 2020,
        "deadLine": "2019-10-30T22:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-10-29T08:31:19.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-10-29T08:31:19.000Z",
        "Reports_type.name": "excelent",
        "companyName": "energy",
    }
]
```

The problem is i get it weird like this:

```
"Reports_type.name"
```

I want the output be:

```
"name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic has been covered before - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148491/how-to-get-join-data-result-without-prefix-table-name-in-sequelize-orm).

To avoid the prefix, attributes must be specified in the main model rather than the included model.  The example below should produce all fields in `Report` plus `Reports_type.name`.  Note: the alias of Reports_type may be a little different than I've guessed - if you get a "field does not exist", find the correct alias from the generated SQL.

```
 models.Report.findAll({
      where: { companyID: [513603324, 515490704, 511493827] },
      include: [{
        model: models.Reports_type,
        attributes:[],    // suppress here
        required: true
      }],
      raw: true,
      attributes: {
         include: [[Sequelize.col("reports_types.name"), "name"]]  // include here; table alias may be a little different!
      }
    })
```