# inner join in single object sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to do inner join using sequelize ORM and it is working fine. But here it is returning in a nested object. How can we convert into a single object?

```js
const caseProtaluserList = await models.Cases.findAll({include: [
    {
        model: models.Merchants, 
        attributes: ['name']
    }
]
```

output

```
{
    "case_Id": "1",
    "merchantId": 1,
    "primary_Email": "addad",
    "description": "dadad",
    "status": "dada",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:29:20.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:29:20.000Z",
    "Merchant": {
        "name": "Waterstone Brands"
    }
}
```

Comment: i want in this format

```
            "case_Id": "1",
            "merchantId": 1,
            "primary_Email": "addad",
            "description": "dadad",
            "status": "dada",
            "createdAt": "2020-02-05T09:29:20.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-02-05T09:29:20.000Z",
            "Merchant": "Waterstone Brands"
```

Comment: I don't think there's such an option. Look the `includeOptions` interface of sequelize: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L3252. You could just manipulate the object after the query.

Comment: Try using raw:true to get flatten result. This might help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502699/return-flat-object-from-sequelize-with-association