# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: model is not associated to otherModel

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I've seen this problem a lot in different forums but I haven't been able to fix it. I'm using Express and PostgreSQL with Sequelize.

Basically I have two models: Campus and academic manager. It's a one to one relation between the two, Campus has one academic manager.

I've implemented both models and the association works, I can see it beeing displayed in mi database in the postgres server. But when I try to implement my get request of campus, I try to include the manager information, without success. I keep receiving the same error:

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: academic_manager is not associated to campus!

I believe my problem has to do with *include*

Here are my code snippets:

**campus.js**

```
const campus = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
    const Campus = sequelize.define('campus', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        manager: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'academic_manager',
                key: 'id'
            }
        } 
    });    

    Campus.associate = models => {
        Campus.hasOne(models.Manager, { foreignKey: 'id'});
    }

    return Campus; 
};

export default campus;
```

**academic_manager.js**

```
const manager = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
    const Manager = sequelize.define('academic_manager', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        } 
    });    

    Manager.associate = models => {
        Manager.belongsTo(models.Campus, { foreignKey: 'id'});
    }

    return Manager; 
};

export default manager;
```

And the get method:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const campus = await req.context.models.Campus.findAll({
        include: [
            { model: req.context.models.Manager }
        ]
    });
    return res.send(campus);
});
```

The get request works without the include. I know the association is achieved because when I describe my campus table and my manager table I have this:

```
TABLE "campus" CONSTRAINT "campus_manager_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (manager) REFERENCES academic_manager(id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was that I wasn't making the associations in my models index. I was missing this:

```
Object.keys(models).forEach(key => {
  if ('associate' in models[key]) {
    models[key].associate(models);
  }
});
```

Always remeber to actually make your associations.

Answer (score 5):

Your model definition has several problems. Sequelize might be confused as to whether you wanted to **associate** the models, or just have them **referencing** each other.

You have added associations which implements relational constraints, but also added reference key which is meant to allow reference but not implement constraints.

Might want to read:

1. [How to implement many to many association in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958683/how-to-implement-many-to-many-association-in-sequelize/25072476#25072476)
2. https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html

I have commented your code:

#### campus.js

```js
const Campus = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
    const Campus = sequelize.define('Campus', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        }
        // this is not correct.
        // read when to use reference key further below
        /* manager: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'academic_manager',
                key: 'id' 
            }

        } */
    });    

    Campus.associate = models => {
        // Campus.hasOne(models.Manager, { foreignKey: 'id'});
        // foreignKey `id` is wrong. Your models already by default have `id`, which is their own.
        // you either define the name as `campus_id`, or just let sequelize handle it for you by not defining it at all and just use `Campus.hasOne(models.Manager)`.
        // but generally it's good practice to define, otherwise when you need it, you have to figure out what did sequelize help you name it as.
        // read: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#providing-the-foreign-key-name-directly
        Campus.hasOne(models.Manager, { foreignKey: 'campus_id'); // this means please inject `campus_id` into `Manager` 
    }

    return Campus; 
};

export default Campus;
```

#### academic_manager.js

```js
const Manager = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>{
    const Manager = sequelize.define('Manager', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });    

    Manager.associate = models => {
        // you don't define foreignKey here. because by doing so you are saying
        // you want to inject this foreignKey into `Campus`, which you are not.
        Manager.belongsTo(models.Campus);
    }

    return Manager; 
};

export default Manager;
```

### Additional Info - When to use this referenceKey?

In relational databases, the rule of thumb is that between any 2 model, you should only have 1 path, otherwise it forms a [cyclic dependency](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38655/Prevent-Circular-References-in-Database-Design), which can potentially cause problems.

#### Imagine you have the third entity `Location`

```
Campus.hasOne(Manager)
Manager.belongsTo(Campus)

Location.hasOne(Campus)
Location.belongsTo(Campus)
```

All is well and good. Lets for a moment imaginatively assume that the `Manager` stays on the `Campus`, you can find out their `Location` like this

```
Manager -> Campus -> Location
```

Until such time you have decided that it is a true statement that `Manager` will always stay in that `Location` and nowhere else, and your application have more frequently required this information, you will be tempted to do this:

```
Location.hasOne(Manager)
Manager.belongsTo(Location)
```

You now have another path `Location -> Manager`, and you completed the circular reference of `Location -> Manager -> Campus -> Location -> Manager....`

To break this, you must make a choice between which relationship is more important, or more commonly accessed. In this case it may seem that the relationship between `Location` and `Manager` is not all that important, then just continue using `Manager -> Campus -> Location`.

#### But you want the cake and also eat it

This is where you don't associate the models, and just use **reference keys** or use `constraints: false`. Read https://sequelize.org/master/manual/constraints-and-circularities.html

`constraints: false` is my usual choice because it still provides me with all the sequelize methods as though the models are associated. But to be very strict, you are by right to be using `reference keys` at most. Then do a manual join, or do 2 queries by using the reference key you found to locate its data on its referenced table.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm new to sequelize so this gets rather confusing. I tried you code corrections, and still got the same error when I attempt to use include in my GET request _SequelizeEagerLoadingError: academic_manager is not associated to campus!_. 
I tried using aliases as one of the links explalined: I deleted the association from campus and added `Manager.belongsTo(models.Campus, { as: 'managers' }`  in the manager model and modified the GET request to `include: 'managers'` but then I got the following error:
_Error: Association with alias "managers" does not exist on campus_

Comment: I tried adding the association in Campus again, but got the same error, specifying the foreign key. And without writing the foreign key too.

Comment: try making all your model names consistent. i think you defined `academic_manager` as the Manager table. And in your associate, it could be Models.academic_manager.

Comment: I realized it was a really dumb mistake, I forgot to actually make the associations happen. This is my first post here, thanks for your answers, should I delete my question? or just update it?

Comment: Keep everything, the answer is clear and might help someone else (like me)