# Create multiple INNER JOINS with Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize ORM with Node.js and I can't get my head around on how to build the following query with it.

```
SELECT service.*, serviceCollection.*, client.companyName, client.idclient 
FROM service 
INNER JOIN serviceCollection 
ON service.serviceCollection_idserviceCollection = serviceCollection.idserviceCollection 
INNER JOIN client 
ON serviceCollection.client_idclient = client.idclient
```

This query works and runs fine when I try it on phpMyAdmin.
The complication is that the Client model has no direct relation with Service, so when trying to do this :

```
Service.findAll({include : [ServiceCollection, Client]}).then(function(service){
    if(service) {
        res.status(200).json(service);
    }
});
```

I get the following error :

```
Unhandled rejection Error: client is not associated to service!
```

How could I prepare the query in a way that would get the client information from the foreignkey in ***serviceCollection*** and not the original model - ***service***.
I can't just use `include` on ***client*** because it will give me the error, I need to associate it to this query some other way and I can't seem to find the solution in the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make join querys using sequelize in nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-querys-using-sequelize-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have a relation set up between servicecollection and client? In that case you can do:

```
Service.findAll({
  include : [
    { 
      model: ServiceCollection, 
      required: true,
      include: [{model: Client, required: true }]}
  ]
});
```

`required: true` creates an inner join, the default is a left join