# How to write mysql join queries using sequelize in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have a MySQL table like this:

[image]

How can I write the following MySQL query using sequelize?

```
select mt.JobId 
from   MyTable as mt join MyTable as mt2 on mt2.JobId = mt.JobId
where  mt.TaskSeq = 0 and mt.TaskState = 'Done' and mt2.TaskSeq = 1 
and mt2.TaskState = 'New'
```

This query returns all the `JobId`s whose `taskA` is in `Done` state and `taskB` is in `New` state.

In this case, it returns `qwert`, and `zxcv`.

After reading a similar stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-querys-using-sequelize-in-nodejs). I get a little confused, because I only have 1 table. Should I use `hasMany` and `belongsTo` in order to create a `join` query in sequelize?

The following is part of my node.js scripts for creating this table

```
var MyTable = conn.define(
'MyTable',
{
    JobId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
    },
    TaskName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    TaskSeq: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    TaskState: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
},
{
    collate: 'utf8mb4_bin'
}
)

MyTable.sync()
module.exports = {
    MyTable, conn
}
```

And this is my sequelize query, which fails to return the `JobId`s I need.

```
MyTable.belongsTo(MyTable, {foreignKey: 'id'})
MyTable.findAll({
attributes: ['JobId'],
where: {
    TaskSeq: 0,
    TaskState: 'DONE'
},
include: [{
    model: MyTable,
    attributes: ['JobId'],
    where: {
        JobId: sequelize.col('MyTable.JobId'),
        TaskSeq: 1,
        TaskState: 'NEW'
    }
}]
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to define the associations so that the include function in your query works.  http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html

Your MyTable.belongsTo(MyTable, {foreignKey: 'id'}) isn't using the correct id is it?  If you are wanting to join on JobId then use it.  I didn't even see and id column in your table above.

or try a raw query:

```
`sequelize.query('select mt.JobId from MyTable as mt join MyTable as mt2 on 
   mt2.JobId = mt.JobId where mt.TaskSeq = 0 and mt.TaskState = 'Done' and 
   mt2.TaskSeq = 1', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
 ).then(myTables => {
   console.log(myTables)
 })`
```

Comment: The `id` column is automatically generated by sequelize.

Comment: I've ran the same code locally and I don't think Sequelize supports table associations back to the same table.  

I do know about the id pk column but what I mean was trying to change: 

`MyTable.belongsTo(MyTable, {foreignKey: 'id'})` to: 

`MyTable.belongsTo(MyTable, {foreignKey: 'JobId'})`  

But with the version I installed, that didn't work either.

I would just use a raw query and get the exact result you want.  http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

If your model has an association with other table you can do something like this:

```
var Product = sequelize.define('Product',{
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'description'
        }
    },{
        classMethods: {
            associate : function(models) {
                Product.belongsTo(Category,{
                    as: 'category',
                    foreignKey: {
                        allowNull: false
                    },
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
                });
            }
        }
    });


Product.findAll({
  include: [{
   model: Category,
   as: "category"     
  }]
})
```

The result will be some like:

```
{
 id:1,
 name:'product1',
 category: {
  id:23,
  name: 'category1'
 }
}
```