# Sequelize how to make a join request?

Tags: node.js, join, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make joined queries with [Sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize).

That's my db :
[image]
What I need is to select all of my relations and get this kind of result:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        State: true,
        FK_User: {
            id: 2,
            Name: "my name"
        },
        FK_Team: {
            id: 3,
            Name: "team name"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

But today I've got this result:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        State: true,
        FK_User: 2,
        FK_Team: 3
    },
    ...
]
```

For each of my relations, I've go to do another request to get datas ...
So I putted a look in this [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-queries-using-sequelize-on-node-js) and in the [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html).
Then I made this code :

```
let User = this.instance.define("User", {
  Name: {
    type: this.libraries.orm.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

let Team = this.instance.define("Team", {
  Name: {
    type: this.libraries.orm.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
});

let Relation = this.instance.define("Relation", {
  State: {
    type: this.libraries.orm.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 0
  }
});

Relation.hasOne(User, {as: "FK_User", foreignKey: "id"});
Relation.hasOne(Team, {as: "FK_Team", foreignKey: "id"});
```

With this code, I haven't got any relation between tables... So I added theses two lines. I don't understand why I need to make a two direction relation, because I don't need to access Relation From User and Team ...

```
User.belongsTo(Relation, {foreignKey: 'FK_User_id'});
Team.belongsTo(Relation, {foreignKey: 'FK_Team_id'});
```

When I do that, I've a FK_User_id in the User table and a FK_Team_id in the Team table ... I don't know how to make this simple relation and get all I need with my futur request and the `include: [User, Team]}` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.hasOne(Relation);
Team.hasOne(Relation);
Relation.belongsTo(Team);
Relation.belongsTo(User);
```

This code seems to work.
I don't know why ...

Answer (score 0):

Here your associations are setup correctly you can join it with `include` :

```
Relation.findAll({
    where : {
        state : true
    }
    include:[
        {
            model : User
        },
        {
            model : Team
        }
    ]
})
```