# NODEJS - Perform INNER JOIN sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to perform an INNER JOIN using sequelize and Node. The actual SQL query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.author, b.image_url, s.novel_status AS status, g.genre 
FROM novels b 
  INNER JOIN genres g 
  ON b.genre = g.id 
  INNER JOIN novel_statuses s 
  ON b.status = s.id
```

Which gives the following response:
[image: response]

Using sequelize as my ORM, I have tried to accomplish the above like this:

```js
getNovel: (req, res) => {
    novelModel.hasMany(statusModel, {
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
    statusModel.belongsTo(novelModel, {
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
    novelModel.hasMany(genreModel, {
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
    genreModel.belongsTo(novelModel, {
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });

    novelModel
      .findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: genreModel,
            required: true,
            attributes: ['genre']
          },
          {
            model: statusModel,
            required: true,
            attributes: ['novel_status']
          }
        ]
      })
      .then(result => res.json(result))
      .catch(err => res.json(err));
  },
```

But then the response is different, i.e. as below: 
[image: response]

My DB: 
[image: db]

I have tried to search for answers, but without any luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make join queries using Sequelize on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-queries-using-sequelize-on-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You should give the name of the Model Framework you use.