# i am getting count as 1 instead of 0 when i did groupby using sequelize in nodejs

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I have two tables "project" and "company". I have created their models as 'Project' and 'Company' in sequelize.

Project table contains

| project_id | company_id | project_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | project1 |
| 2 | 2 | project2 |
| 3 | 2 | project3 |

Company table contains

| company_id | company_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz |
| 2 | test |
| 3 | abc |

my requirement is to get all companies in the Company table and the no of projects they have.

i have wrote the query in sequelize as

```
const result = await Company.findAll({
    attributes: [ ['company_id', 'id'] ,'company_name', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'Project.project_id'), 'no_of_projects'] ],
    include: [{ model: Project, attributes: [] }],
    group: ['company_id'],
    order: [
        [sortBy, sortOrder]
    ],
    offset: index,
    limit: limit,
    subQuery: false
})
```

but i am getting no_of_projects as 1 instead of 0 for company "abc" as it doesn't have any project. I need to get no_of_projects as 0 if there is no project for the company. i am new to sql and sequelize. can anyone please help me in solving this. thanks in advance.

these are the associations

Company.associate = function(models) {
Company.hasMany(models.Project, {
foreignKey: "company_id"
})
}

Project.associate = function(models) {
Project.belongsTo(models.Company, {
foreignKey: 'company_id',
})
}

Comment: Have you defined the associations while creating the tables??.. with foreign key as company_id between projects and company

Comment: Yes. i have defined. You can find the associations in the question. Just now i have edited it.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-queries-using-sequelize-on-node-js might help

Comment: Sorry i could'nt find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the mistake in my sequelize query.
Instead of

```
[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'Project.project_id')
```

It worked when I replace that with

```
[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('project_id'))
```

I need to specify that as a column to sequelize otherwise it is considering empty string as a value. That's why I got count as 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want SQL then you can use following:

```
select c.company_id, c.company_name, count(p.project_id) as num_of_project
  from company c left join project p on p.comapny_id = c.company_id
group by c.company_id, c.company_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. But i want the query in sequelize.