# complicated query using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have 3 tables .. profile, player, garage

profile has winCount , loseCount

player has username

garage has carNumber

they are all connected with each other using the id from player table (playerId in table garage and profile)

i want to get the
top 20 winCount , username , carnumber

i am trying this code

```
let racers = await Profile.findAll({
            where: {
                carRaceWinCount: {
                    [Op.gt]: 0
                }
            },
            limit: 20,
            order: [
                ['carRaceWinCount', 'DESC']
            ]
        })
            .then((races: any) => {
                Garage.findAll({
                    where: {
                        playerId: races.id
                    },
                    attributes : ['carNum']
                })
                Player.findAll({
                    where :{
                        id : races.id
                    },
                    attributes : ['username']
                })
            })
```

and it is not working
what is the best way to get this query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make join queries using Sequelize on Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460270/how-to-make-join-queries-using-sequelize-on-node-js)

Comment: @TobiasS. I do not think so :/

Comment: Do you know the appropriate SQL-Query to achieve your goal?

Comment: @TobiasS. Tbh no

Comment: How many profiles and garages can a certain user have?

Comment: @Anatoly in the models file .. the player has many garages

Answer (score 0):

If you have these associations:

```js
Player.hasMany(Profile, { foreignKey: 'playerId' })
Player.hasMany(Garage, { foreignKey: 'playerId' })
Profile.belongsTo(Player, { foreignKey: 'playerId' })
```

then the query might look like this

```js
await Profile.findAll({
            where: {
                winCount: {
                    [Op.gt]: 0
                }
            },
            limit: 20,
            include: [{
              model: Player,
              include: [{
                model: Garage,
                // this is important option to query all garames as separate queries, Otherwise you will get wrong count of profiles.
                separate: true
              }]
            }]
            order: [
                ['winCount', 'DESC']
            ]
        })
```

Comment: ok this is almost working but the garage data in not fetched .... 
this is the response    "garages": []

Comment: Then check data in DB and asociations

Comment: no i am sure DB has rows and the associations are correct .. i tried the same query but without the " separate " and it fetched data but the order of players are different ... so why this is happening ?

Comment: `separate` is needed for correct fetching players because you limiting them by a certain count. Otherwise if you have 1 profile with 1 player with 10 garages and other profile with 1 player and 10 garages and all other profiles with 1 player and 1 garage you might get only 2 profiles instead of 20 because in SQL these two tables are multiplied.